# Python MySQL data manipulation

Tags: python

i have an assignment for uni, i've run into a wall, and i can't seem to get it working no amtter what i try.

So, this assignment is focused on accessing a MySQL database from Python, and viewing and arranging the data. The database is called inb104 and two tables exist, cars_for_sale and car_details.

Here is my code

```
def top_N_expensive(num_of_highest):
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='root',\
                                                                 db='inb104')
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "SELECT cars_for_sale.make, cars_for_sale.model, +'$'+car_details.price \
            FROM cars_for_sale, car_details WHERE cars_for_sale.CarId = car_details.CarId \
            ORDER BY price DESC,price LIMIT " + str(num_of_highest)
cursor.execute(sql) 
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row[0], row[1], row[2]
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Now when i run this code the test cases fail, this is just one of the test cases but the rest are the same

```
File "__main__", line 4, in __main__
Failed example:
top_N_expensive(10)
Expected:
VOLKSWAGEN GOLF $1300000
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $329990
BMW 3 $299990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $249990
PORSCHE 911 $249990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $224990
PORSCHE 911 $219990
PORSCHE 911 $190000
PORSCHE 911 $184990
BMW M5 $180000
Got:
VOLKSWAGEN GOLF 1300000.0
MERCEDES-BENZ SL 329990.0
BMW 3 299990.0
MERCEDES-BENZ SL 249990.0
PORSCHE 911 249990.0
MERCEDES-BENZ SL 224990.0
PORSCHE 911 219990.0
PORSCHE 911 190000.0
PORSCHE 911 184990.0
BMW M5 180000.0
```

As you can see, it's failing because there is a zero at the end and there is no $ at the beginning, anyone know the problem?

EDIT: After adding this new code

```
for row in rows:
    print "%s %s $%d" % (row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

I got 3/4 test case passes, i don't know why the last one isnt passing, but here is the test case dump

```
Trying:
top_N_expensive(10)
Expecting:
VOLKSWAGEN GOLF $1300000
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $329990
BMW 3 $299990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $249990
PORSCHE 911 $249990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $224990
PORSCHE 911 $219990
PORSCHE 911 $190000
PORSCHE 911 $184990
BMW M5 $180000

Warning (from warnings module):
File "Z:\Documents\top_N_expensive.py", line 82
cursor.execute(sql)
Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '$'
ok
Trying:
top_N_expensive(15)
Expecting:
VOLKSWAGEN GOLF $1300000
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $329990
BMW 3 $299990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $249990
PORSCHE 911 $249990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $224990
PORSCHE 911 $219990
PORSCHE 911 $190000
PORSCHE 911 $184990
BMW M5 $180000
MERCEDES-BENZ E55 $179990
MERCEDES-BENZ CLS $179990
PORSCHE 911 $165000
PORSCHE 911 $164900
PORSCHE 911 $161950
**********************************************************************
File "__main__", line 17, in __main__
Failed example:
top_N_expensive(15)
Expected:
VOLKSWAGEN GOLF $1300000
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $329990
BMW 3 $299990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $249990
PORSCHE 911 $249990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $224990
PORSCHE 911 $219990
PORSCHE 911 $190000
PORSCHE 911 $184990
BMW M5 $180000
MERCEDES-BENZ E55 $179990
MERCEDES-BENZ CLS $179990
PORSCHE 911 $165000
PORSCHE 911 $164900
PORSCHE 911 $161950
Got:
VOLKSWAGEN GOLF $1300000
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $329990
BMW 3 $299990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $249990
PORSCHE 911 $249990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $224990
PORSCHE 911 $219990
PORSCHE 911 $190000
PORSCHE 911 $184990
BMW M5 $180000
MERCEDES-BENZ CLS $179990
MERCEDES-BENZ E55 $179990
PORSCHE 911 $165000
PORSCHE 911 $164900
PORSCHE 911 $161950
Trying:
top_N_expensive(1)
Expecting:
VOLKSWAGEN GOLF $1300000
ok
Trying:
top_N_expensive(0)
Expecting nothing
ok
1 items had no tests:
__main__.top_N_expensive
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
1 of   4 in __main__
4 tests in 2 items.
3 passed and 1 failed.
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

So, don't know why this is failing now, very strange.

Heres the updated Query

```
def top_N_expensive(num_of_highest):
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='root',\
                                                                 db='inb104')
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "SELECT cars_for_sale.make, cars_for_sale.model, +'$'+car_details.price \
            FROM cars_for_sale, car_details WHERE cars_for_sale.CarId = car_details.CarId \
            ORDER BY price DESC, make, model DESC" + str(num_of_highest)
cursor.execute(sql) 
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print "%s %s $%d" % (row[0], row[1], row[2]) 
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Test cases

```
Trying:
top_N_expensive(10)
Expecting:
VOLKSWAGEN GOLF $1300000
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $329990
BMW 3 $299990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $249990
PORSCHE 911 $249990
MERCEDES-BENZ SL $224990
PORSCHE 911 $219990
PORSCHE 911 $190000
PORSCHE 911 $184990
BMW M5 $180000
**********************************************************************
File "__main__", line 4, in __main__
Failed example:
top_N_expensive(10)
Exception raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\doctest.py", line 1254, in __run
    compileflags, 1) in test.globs
  File "<doctest __main__[0]>", line 1, in <module>
    top_N_expensive(10)
  File "Z:\Documentstop_N_expensive.py", line 82, in top_N_expensive
    cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC10' at line 1")
```

Comment: As to the zeroes, looks like you need to run the values through the Python float function. As to no $, you might need to print that.

Comment: Do you need to get the result using sql statement itself or you can format the output yourself. If it is later you prolly already have the solution.

Comment: I can format the output i guess, either way would work, theres no academic limitations on either, just not sure how i would go about it. Sorry i am new to the Python programming.

Comment: The new failure is because "MERCEDES-BENZ E55" and "MERCEDES-BENZ CLS" are reversed. Your ORDER BY clause doesn't make sense. I think you want `ORDER BY price DESC, make, model`.

Answer (score 3):

A slight variation on the previous:

```
for row in rows:
    print("{} {} ${:0.0f}".format(*row))
```

Edit: a follow-up to your edit - you're returning CLS before E55, it wants them the other way. Check your sort order; try

```
... ORDER BY price DESC, make, model DESC
```

Comment: I tried using your edit and it seemed to make all test cases fail

Comment: ! ok, unexpected... can you show one of the resulting failures' 'expected' vs 'got'?

Comment: Hi, i have edited the original post at the bottom

Comment: it looks like you removed ' LIMIT ' from your query string, resulting in 'ORDER BY price DESC, make, model DESC 12' (which is bad syntax). Try sticking LIMIT back in.

Comment: Looks like that fixed it, i shouldnt have removed the limit part. Thanks for your help, all test cases passed, and i have a better understand now, wee!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in the `SELECT` statement you could try with [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [`ROUND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('$', ROUND(car_details.price)) AS price FROM car_details;
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this question [currency formatting in puython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python), it is most likely what you want. as a more hacky way you can convert to strings and the use string manipulation.

**EDIT**

copied from the above referenced question

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, '' )
'English_United States.1252'
>>> locale.currency( 188518982.18 )
'$188518982.18'
>>> locale.currency( 188518982.18, grouping=True )
'$188,518,982.18'
```

Comment: How about putting an example here?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some simple [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html) should get you there:

```
for row in rows:
    print "%s %s $%d" % (row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

The `%s` characters are for outputting strings. `%d` is for outputting integers (numbers with no decimal part), so it's a bit of a cheat. You could also use `%.0f` to show a float printed with 0 decimal places (whereas `%.2f` would show the number to two decimal places).

Comment: Cheers for the assitance Tom, i have edited the original post with the further test case, just one which seems to be failing but for the life of me i could not figure out why.