# How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ipython, dataframe

I would like to display a pandas dataframe with a given format using `print()` and the IPython `display()`. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([123.4567, 234.5678, 345.6789, 456.7890],
                  index=['foo','bar','baz','quux'],
                  columns=['cost'])
print df

         cost
foo   123.4567
bar   234.5678
baz   345.6789
quux  456.7890
```

I would like to somehow coerce this into printing

```
         cost
foo   $123.46
bar   $234.57
baz   $345.68
quux  $456.79
```

without having to modify the data itself or create a copy, just change the way it is displayed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is `cost` the only float column, or are there other float columns that should not be formatted with `$`?

Comment: I'd like to do it for the cost column only (my real data has other columns)

Comment: i realize that once $ is attached, the data type automatically changes to object.

Answer (score 455, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format
df = pd.DataFrame([123.4567, 234.5678, 345.6789, 456.7890],
                  index=['foo','bar','baz','quux'],
                  columns=['cost'])
print(df)
```

yields

```
        cost
foo  $123.46
bar  $234.57
baz  $345.68
quux $456.79
```

but this only works if you want *every* float to be formatted with a dollar sign.

Otherwise, if you want dollar formatting for some floats only, then I think you'll have to pre-modify the dataframe (converting those floats to strings):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([123.4567, 234.5678, 345.6789, 456.7890],
                  index=['foo','bar','baz','quux'],
                  columns=['cost'])
df['foo'] = df['cost']
df['cost'] = df['cost'].map('${:,.2f}'.format)
print(df)
```

yields

```
         cost       foo
foo   $123.46  123.4567
bar   $234.57  234.5678
baz   $345.68  345.6789
quux  $456.79  456.7890
```

Comment: This solution still works properly for me as of pandas 0.22.

Comment: as shown e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30691921/288875), you can modify the options only for the a given block by using `with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '${:,.2f}'.format'):`

Comment: Extra `'` before the closing parenthesis on the comment of @AndreHolzner; otherwise, it works like a charm!

Comment: This answer can be enchanced by the use of locales. For more information, look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/320951/3288004

Comment: Hey @unbunto. Kudos on your solution. Exactly what I was looking for. When I spool a df into an excel file (using openpyxl), I'm getting a "number stored as text" error. Any idea how can I avoid that?

Comment: If you want to use f-strings instead, then list comprehension works nicely `df['cost'] = [f"${x:.2f}" for x in df['cost']]`

Comment: link to the format specs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 96):

If you don't want to modify the dataframe, you could use a custom formatter for that column.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format
df = pd.DataFrame([123.4567, 234.5678, 345.6789, 456.7890],
                  index=['foo','bar','baz','quux'],
                  columns=['cost'])


print df.to_string(formatters={'cost':'${:,.2f}'.format})
```

yields

```
        cost
foo  $123.46
bar  $234.57
baz  $345.68
quux $456.79
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the formatter to work on a multilevel column?

Comment: AFAICT, this example works without the second line `pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format`

Answer (score 84):

[As of Pandas 0.17 there is now a styling system](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) which essentially provides formatted views of a DataFrame using [Python format strings](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

constants = pd.DataFrame(
    [('pi', np.pi), ('e', np.e)],
    columns=['name', 'value'])
C = constants.style.format({'name':'~~ {} ~~', 'value':'--> {:15.10f} <--'})
C
```

which displays

[image: table showing formatted values]

This is a view object; the DataFrame itself does not change formatting, but updates in the DataFrame are reflected in the view:

```
constants.name = ['pie', 'eek']
C
```

[image: table showing updated values]

However it appears to have some limitations:

- Adding new rows and/or columns in-place seems to cause inconsistency in the styled view (doesn't add row/column labels):

  ```
  constants.loc[2] = dict(name='bogus', value=123.456)
  constants['comment'] = ['fee', 'fie', 'fo']
  constants
  ```

  [image: table showing unformatted values in new row and column]

  which looks ok but:

  ```
  C
  ```

  [image: table showing formatting problems (misalignment, unformatted values)]
- Formatting works only for values, not index entries:

  ```
  constants = pd.DataFrame(
      [('pi', np.pi), ('e', np.e)],
      columns=['name', 'value']
      ).set_index('name')
  C = constants.style.format({'name':'~~ {} ~~', 'value':'--> {:15.10f} <--'})
  C
  ```

  [image: table showing formatted values but unformatted index]

Comment: Can I use the DataFrame.style from inside the interpreter?

Comment: [`.format_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format_index.html) was added in Pandas 1.4.0

Comment: As of Pandas 2.0.1, new row/column labels are added properly, but the values are still left unformatted.

Answer (score 43):

Similar to unutbu above, you could also use `applymap` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([123.4567, 234.5678, 345.6789, 456.7890],
                  index=['foo','bar','baz','quux'],
                  columns=['cost'])

df = df.applymap("${0:.2f}".format)
```

Comment: I like using this approach before calling `df.to_csv()` to make sure all the columns in my `.csv` file have the same "digit width."  Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

If you do not want to change the display format permanently, and perhaps apply a new format later on, I personally favour the use of a resource manager (the `with` statement in Python). In your case you could do something like this:

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '${:0.2f}'.format):
   print(df)
```

If you happen to need a different format further down in your code, you can change it by varying just the format in the snippet above.

Answer (score 11):

I like using pandas.apply() with python format().

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1.357, 1.489, 2.333333])

make_float = lambda x: "${:,.2f}".format(x)
s.apply(make_float)
```

Also, it can be easily used with multiple columns...

```
df = pd.concat([s, s * 2], axis=1)

make_floats = lambda row: "${:,.2f}, ${:,.3f}".format(row[0], row[1])
df.apply(make_floats, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 11):

Instead of messing with `pd.options` and globally affecting the rendering of your data frames, you can use [DataFrame.style.format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values) and only style the rendering of one data frame.

```
df.style.format({
  'cost': lambda val: f'${val:,.2f}',
})

>>>
>>>            cost
>>> ---------------
>>> foo   $123.4567
>>> bar   $234.5678
>>> baz   $345.6789
>>> quux   $456.789
```

## Explanation

The function `df.style.format` takes a dict whose keys map to the column names you want to style, and the value is a callable that receives each value for the specified column(s), and must return a string, representing the formatted value. This only affects the *rendering* of the data frame, and does not change the underlying data.

Comment: `df.style` creates a html-table which is not nice to look at when printed to a text-interface

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays, my preferred solution is to use a context manager just for displaying a dataframe:

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '${:,.2f}'.format):
    display(df)
```

The format will be valid just for the display of this dataframe

Answer (score 4):

You can also set locale to your region and set float_format to use a currency format. This will automatically set $ sign for currency in USA.

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")

pd.set_option("float_format", locale.currency)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [123.4567, 234.5678, 345.6789, 456.7890],
    index=["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"],
    columns=["cost"],
)
print(df)

        cost
foo  $123.46
bar  $234.57
baz  $345.68
quux $456.79
```

Answer (score 2):

summary:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame({'money': [100.456, 200.789], 'share': ['100,000', '200,000']})
    print(df)
    print(df.to_string(formatters={'money': '${:,.2f}'.format}))
    for col_name in ('share',):
        df[col_name] = df[col_name].map(lambda p: int(p.replace(',', '')))
    print(df)
    """
        money    share
    0  100.456  100,000
    1  200.789  200,000

        money    share
    0 $100.46  100,000
    1 $200.79  200,000

         money   share
    0  100.456  100000
    1  200.789  200000
    """
```