# How do I change data-type of pandas data frame to string with a defined format?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, pandas, format

I'm starting to tear my hair out with this - so I hope someone can help. I have a pandas DataFrame that was created from an Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl. The resulting DataFrame looks like:

```
print image_name_data
     id           image_name
0  1001  1001_mar2014_report
1  1002  1002_mar2014_report
2  1003  1003_mar2014_report

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

…with the following datatypes:

```
print image_name_data.dtypes
id            float64
image_name     object
dtype: object
```

The issue is that the numbers in the id column are, in fact, identification numbers and I need to treat them as strings. I've tried converting the id column to strings using:

```
image_name_data['id'] = image_name_data['id'].astype('str')
```

This seems a bit ugly but it does produce a variable of type 'object' rather than 'float64':

```
print image_name_data.dyptes
id            object
image_name    object
dtype: object
```

However, the strings that are created have a decimal point, as shown:

```
print image_name_data
       id           image_name
0  1001.0  1001_mar2014_report
1  1002.0  1002_mar2014_report
2  1003.0  1003_mar2014_report

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

How can I convert a float64 column in a pandas DataFrame to a string with a given format (in this case, for example, '%10.0f')?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem but have you tried converting it to an integer first?

```
image_name_data['id'] = image_name_data['id'].astype(int).astype('str')
```

Then, regarding your more general question you could use `map` ([as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-using-a-format-string-for-columns)). In your case:

```
image_name_data['id'] = image_name_data['id'].map('{:.0f}'.format)
```

Comment: Ta-dah! Both suggestions seem to work perfectly. Thanks very much! I'm afraid I don't have a high enough reputation to rate this answer - but would if I could.

Comment: @user1718097 Glad to hear it. I'm also new to SO but I think that you can mark it as the "best answer" or something.

Comment: Converting to int first fails if there are any NaN/null values (error message is "*** ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer"). I have data that is either int or missing, but astype('str') happily adds '.0' to every number... not sure how to prevent this.

Answer (score 8):

If you could reload this, you might be able to use dtypes argument.

```
pd.read_csv(..., dtype={'COL_NAME':'str'})
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting this in a new answer because no linebreaks / codeblocks in comments.
I assume you want those nans to turn into a blank string? I couldn't find a nice way to do this, only do the ugly method:

```
s = pd.Series([1001.,1002.,None])
a = s.loc[s.isnull()].fillna('')
b = s.loc[s.notnull()].astype(int).astype(str)
result = pd.concat([a,b])
```