# Dataframe's column conversion from type object to int / float using Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types, sklearn-pandas

### The Scenario

I have 2 CSV files (1) u.Data and (2) prediction_matrix which I need to read and write into a **Single Dataframe**, once done it is processed for Clustering based on int / float values it will contain

### The Problem

I'm done combining the 2 CSVs into 1 Dataframe named **AllData.csv**, but the type of columns holding value have a different type now **(object)**, as shown below (with a warning)

```
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (0,1,2) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
UDATA -------------
uid    int64
iid    int64
rat    int64
dtype: object
PRED_MATRIX -------
uid      int64
iid      int64
rat    float64
dtype: object
AllDATA -----------
uid    object
iid    object
rat    object
dtype: object
```

P.S.  I know how to use `low_memory=False` and that just supresses the warning.

### The Possible Cause

```
with open('AllData.csv', 'w') as handle:
    udata_df.to_csv(handle, index=False)
    pred_matrix.to_csv(handle, index=False)
```

Since, I need to write 2 CSVs into Single DF *handle* object is used and probably that turns all the values into its type. Can anything preserve the data type applying the same logic?

Unhelpful References taken so far:

1. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276503/how-to-i-change-data-type-of-pandas-data-frame-to-string-with-a-defined-format)
2. [This two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950374/converting-a-column-within-pandas-dataframe-from-int-to-string)
3. [This too!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns)

Comment: Here's something I'll like to `add AD_Matrix = AllData.drop_duplicates(subset=['uid','iid'])` so I guess that removes the header. Here's the o/p `sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (0,1,2) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
UDATA -------------
uid    int64
iid    int64
rat    int64
dtype: object
PRED_MATRIX -------
uid      int64
iid      int64
rat    float64
dtype: object
AllDATA -----------
196    object
242    object
3      object
dtype: object` @jezrael

Comment: No, `AllData.drop_duplicates(subset=['uid','iid'])` dont remove header, only duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem your header in second `DataFrame` is written too, so need parametr `header=False`:

```
with open('AllData.csv', 'w') as handle:
    udata_df.to_csv(handle, index=False)
    pred_matrix.to_csv(handle, index=False, header=False)
```

Another solution is `mode=a` for append second `DataFrame`:

```
f = 'AllData.csv'
udata_df.to_csv(f, index=False)
pred_matrix.to_csv(f,header=False, index=False, mode='a')
```

Or use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
f = 'AllData.csv'
pd.concat([udata_df, pred_matrix]).to_csv(f, index=False)
```

**Sample**:

```
udata_df = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[1,2],
                         'iid':[8,9],
                         'rat':[0,3]})

pred_matrix = udata_df * 10
```

Third row is `header`:

```
with open('AllData.csv', 'w') as handle:
    udata_df.to_csv(handle, index=False)
    pred_matrix.to_csv(handle, index=False)

f = 'AllData.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(f)
print (df)
   iid  rat  uid
0    8    0    1
1    9    3    2
2  iid  rat  uid
3   80    0   10
4   90   30   20
```

After parameter `header=False` it working correctly:

```
with open('AllData.csv', 'w') as handle:
    udata_df.to_csv(handle, index=False)
    pred_matrix.to_csv(handle, index=False, header=False)

f = 'AllData.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(f)
print (df)
   iid  rat  uid
0    8    0    1
1    9    3    2
2   80    0   10
3   90   30   20
```

mode `append` solution:

```
f = 'AllData.csv'
udata_df.to_csv(f, index=False)
pred_matrix.to_csv(f,header=False, index=False, mode='a')
df = pd.read_csv(f)
print (df)
   iid  rat  uid
0    8    0    1
1    9    3    2
2   80    0   10
3   90   30   20
```

`concat` solution:

```
f = 'AllData.csv'
pd.concat([udata_df, pred_matrix]).to_csv(f, index=False)
df = pd.read_csv(f)
print (df)
   iid  rat  uid
0    8    0    1
1    9    3    2
2   80    0   10
3   90   30   20
```

Comment: Very well compiled the problem Jez!

Answer (score 0):

`with open` method is unnecessary in your case as you can simply concatenate two matrixes and then save it to csv only using pandas like below:

`df = pd.concat([udata_df, pred_matrix], axis=1)
df.to_csv(encoding='utf-8')`