# How to add a trailing zeros to a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column that I would like to be formatted to two decimal places.

Such that:

10.1

Appears as:

10.10

How can I do that? I have already tried rounding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add zeros to a float after the decimal point in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619096/add-zeros-to-a-float-after-the-decimal-point-in-python)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.6 or later you can use f strings. Check out this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45310389/12229158

```
>>> a = 10.1234
>>> f'{a:.2f}'
'10.12'
```

Comment: How do you do this for a whole column?

Comment: I think the most straightforward way is a list comprehensions, as suggested on another thread. This would be: 

df['b'] = [f'{a:.2f}' for a in df['column']].

This creates a new column but you could swap 'b' for the column of interest to overwrite, or drop the old column after creating this new one.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished by mapping a string format object to the column of floats:

`df.colName.map('{:.2f}'.format)`

(Credit to [exp1orer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22276757/11715606))

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
```

Note that this will **only** display two decimals for every float in your dataframes.
To go back to normal:

```py
pd.reset_option('display.float_format')
```

Comment: How would you do this for a single column?

Comment: @David df.style.format({'col': "{:,.2f}"}) if 'col' is the name of your column.

Comment: This was perfect for displaying currency without displaying a symbol.  This was particularly valuable when writing to an Excel file with Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

[From pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

**Padding numbers**

For floating points the padding value represents the length of the complete output. In the example below we want our output to have at least 6 characters with 2 after the decimal point.

```py
'{:06.2f}'.format(3.141592653589793)
```

The `:06` is the length of your output regardless of how many digits are in your input. The `.2` indicates you want 2 places after the decimal point. The `f` indicates you want a float output.

**Output**

```
003.14
```

Comment: How would you do this for a whole column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to format the numbers.

```
df['value'].apply('{:.2f}'.format)
```