# Pandas Python: why does np.round() 3.601626 to 2 dp returns 3.6?

Tags: python, pandas, rounding, dataframe

I'm trying to round some floats in a df to 2 dp but all multiples of 10 are rounded to 1 dp, so 3.60 would be 3.6 and 12.40 would be 12.4...

I have a df:

```
Values           A         B         C         D
Question                                                                                                    
A2         4.08642  4.144279  3.601626  3.983852
```

my code

```
np.round(df,2)
```

output

```
Values        A     B    C     D
Question                                                                                                    
A2         4.09  4.14  3.6  3.98
```

expected output

```
Values        A     B     C     D
Question                                                                                                    
A2         4.09  4.14  3.60  3.98
```

how can I force np.round to display '3.6' as '3.60'?

FYI - I don't want to use a string formatter because I have to round these numbers.

Comment: "I don't want to use a string formatter because I have to round these numbers" - how are those two things in any way related? Why would having to round the numbers make you not want to use string formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with the rounding, but with the way pandas displays the DataFrame.

You can set `float_format` like:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format
```

As explained in more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20937592/2096752).

Comment: This works at a superficial level as doing mean_df.values still returns [[ 4.09  4.14  3.6   3.98]]

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formater and then use Decimal function form library decimal to return number again:

Example code:

```
import decimal
print(decimal.Decimal("{:.2f}".format(3.6)))
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to change the underlying dtype which decimal will do

Answer (score 1):

Another way to set the `pandas` `display.float_format` option:

```
>>> pd.set_option('float_format', '{:,.2f}'.format)
```

Comment: How is this different from shx2's answer?

Comment: @edchum one uses `pd.options.display.float_format  = ` and the other uses `pd.set_option(...)`.

Comment: They are both the same underlying option

Comment: Different Syntax. Some prefer one over the other.

Comment: Thanks, had to go with shx2 because he was first to answer.

Comment: No problem. If it was in any way helpful to you, or anyone else in the future, then job done.