# dataframe.describe() suppress scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I suppress scientific notation output from dataframe.describe():

```
contrib_df["AMNT"].describe()

count    1.979680e+05
mean     5.915134e+02
std      1.379618e+04
min     -1.750000e+05
25%      4.000000e+01
50%      1.000000e+02
75%      2.500000e+02
max      3.000000e+06
Name: AMNT, dtype: float64
```

My data is of type float64:

```
contrib_df["AMNT"].dtypes

dtype('float64')
```

Comment: So what do you want instead? `.describe` returns a `DataFrame`, so you can simply use `.drop` to remove rows you don't want. If you just want one thing like `count` you can use `.count` by itself. Or you can create your own `describe` function to only return whatever you are interested in.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20937592/1577947 using something like `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format`?

Comment: @Jarad Perfect. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Jarad! Please post it as answer to be accepted by @mfabi as he said before. This should be the write way to get rid of scientific numbers which appears in pandas and are displayed by default. Thank you!!

Answer (score 131, accepted):

For single column:

```
contrib_df["AMNT"].describe().apply(lambda x: format(x, 'f'))
```

For entire DataFrame (as suggested by @databyte )

```
df.describe().apply(lambda s: s.apply('{0:.5f}'.format))
```

For whole DataFrame (as suggested by @Jayen):

```
contrib_df.describe().apply(lambda s: s.apply(lambda x: format(x, 'g')))
```

As the function describe returns a data frame, what the above function does is, it simply formats each row to the regular format.
I wrote this answer because I was having a though, in my mind, that was
** It's pointless to get the count of 95 as 95.00000e+01**
Also in our regular format its easier to compare.

Before applying the above function we were getting

```
count    9.500000e+01
mean     5.621943e+05
std      2.716369e+06
min      4.770000e+02
25%      2.118160e+05
50%      2.599960e+05
75%      3.121170e+05
max      2.670423e+07
Name: salary, dtype: float64
```

After applying, we get

```
count          95.000000
mean       562194.294737
std       2716369.154553
min           477.000000
25%        211816.000000
50%        259996.000000
75%        312117.000000
max      26704229.000000
Name: salary, dtype: object
```

Comment: for anyone trying to do this on a dataframe and not a series, it's: `contrib_df.describe().apply(lambda s: s.apply(lambda x: format(x, 'g')))`

Comment: @Jayen - any idea how to round it up / down?

Comment: @SCool - I believe `x` is a normal python float so you should be able to use `format(math.ceil(x), 'g')`

Comment: @Jayen won't using `g` defeat the point? From the docs: "This rounds the number to p significant digits and then **formats the result in either fixed-point format or in scientific notation, depending on its magnitude.**"

Comment: This didn't work for me, got `unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__`

Comment: @JosephGarvin yes, sorry i can't edit it now.  i wanted `g` for my case but the answer to the question should be `f`.  i was just trying to show how to do it to a dataframe.

Comment: Without having to nest lambdas: `df.describe().apply(lambda s: s.apply('{0:.5f}'.format))`