# Pandas describe () returns nonsense figures if values are large

Tags: pandas, return, describe

I use Pandas describe () and wanna check the basic statistic info of my data. However, the result of my last column looks weird. The actual values of R&D expense are all around 70-500 thousand, even though I don't think this is the main reason. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks a lot.

My codes:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('.......')
print (df.describe())
```

The result:

The results in last column are all like 3.530000e+02, 5.239104e+05, 9.672606e+05...etc

[image]

Comment: Why do you say they look weird? Is it because its in scientific notation? Or because you think values are not compatible with your data frame? because seem reasonable to me (considering values between 70.000 and 500.000)

Comment: If you want to suppress scientific notation, there are several threads on this (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347689/dataframe-describe-suppress-scientific-notation/47207283) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737300/suppressing-scientific-notation-in-pandas) ). Just so you understand these "nonsense figures", `e+05` means `10^5` i.e. 100000. So `3.53e+02` means `353`

Comment: Thanks ! Now I understand what 'e' means here.