# Pandas reads integer column in scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas

For some reason, when I import my `csv` file with `pd.read_csv`, one of my integer columns (number of followers) is read in scientific notation, even though my values are whole numbers and clearly not in scientific notation.

See below what I see when I call `df["num_followers"].describe()`

I've looked at all the answers for "suppress scientific notation" on here but haven't found any solution that works.

`df['num_followers'].apply(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))` simply turned my values to `str`. I tried converting to `astype("float")` with no success, values are still in scientific notation, which is messing up my calculations. Any ideas how I can change it to `int`?

```
count    1.200000e+02
mean     4.959472e+04
std      3.816126e+05
min      0.000000e+00
25%      6.725000e+01
50%      2.165000e+02
75%      5.932500e+02
max      4.021842e+06
Name: num_followers, dtype: float64
```

**EDIT**

I tried one of the answers below, also to no success:

```
IN: df_train = pd.read_csv("social_media_train.csv", index_col = [0])
df_train["num_followers"].describe()

OUT: count    5.760000e+02
mean     8.530724e+04
std      9.101485e+05
min      0.000000e+00
25%      3.900000e+01
50%      1.505000e+02
75%      7.160000e+02
max      1.533854e+07
Name: num_followers, dtype: float64

IN: df_train['num_followers'] = df_train['num_followers'].apply(np.int64)
df_train["num_followers"].describe()

OUT:count    5.760000e+02
mean     8.530724e+04
std      9.101485e+05
min      0.000000e+00
25%      3.900000e+01
50%      1.505000e+02
75%      7.160000e+02
max      1.533854e+07
Name: num_followers, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dataframe.describe() suppress scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347689/dataframe-describe-suppress-scientific-notation)

Comment: Using `df_train["num_followers"].describe().apply(lambda x: format(x, 'f'))` worked but how can I then keep the values in non-scientific notation after? If you call `describe()` after, you'll just see the same exponential values again

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672301/7851470

Comment: Did you got answer for this question? If yes, Can you please update working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.int64` with apply (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.types.html).

```
import numpy as np

df['num_followers'] = df['num_followers'].apply(np.int64)
```

Comment: This did not work, unfortunately. The column still in exponential notation

Comment: @MarielleDado Are you sure? It works on my computer and I don't see why should not in your case.

Comment: Yes, I just updated my post with my results based on your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dtype=` option in `pd.read_csv`, e.g.

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', dtype={'num_followers': np.int64})
```

You can of course specify dtypes for additional columns in the dict there.

Comment: I already tried converting the data type after importing, with `astype()`, would this be any different?

Comment: This will throw an annoying error such as `"Integer column has NA values in column 1"` if the column trying to be set as an integer happens to have a blank value.