# How to convert to MB or KB the pandas describe table?

Tags: python, pandas, networking, data-science, byte

```
df.describe()
```

[image]

I have a network dataset. To be able to understand the dataset better, I want to find a way to convert the numbers to MB or KB for packets and bytes.

```
df.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just divide the column by `1024` to get it in KB or `1024*1024` to get it in MB.

```py
cols = ['TotBytes', 'SrcBytes', 'DstBytes']

for c in cols:
    df[c] = df[c] / 1024
    # In case you need to round then do..
    # df[c] = (df[c] / 1024).round(0)
```

There is some [confusion](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13815/files-size-units-kib-vs-kb-vs-kb) as to whether KB is `1000` or `1024` so you can divide by `1000` too if you wish.

---

**Update**

If in addition you want to make it easier to read by not showing the scientific `e+` notation, then you could follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347689/dataframe-describe-suppress-scientific-notation) answer:

```py
df.describe().apply(lambda s: s.apply('{0:.2f}'.format))
```

Comment: `df.describe().apply(lambda s: s.apply('{0:.2f}'.format))` This helped me a lot! I was confused about KB&MB in Wireshark, which unit to use, I am just going to divide /1024 as you suggested!