# Python pandas pct_change return number with % sign and data type as float

Tags: python, pandas, format

When calculating the percentage change on a pandas dataframe, is there a way to show the result as for example 5.00% (float) instead of 0.05?

df.pct_change() will return float numbers without % sign, but I do need the numbers with % in float though, since I will need to later highlight some cells in the dataframe based upon some calculations.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/23922119/190597. Just use the formatting function `'{:.2%}'.format` instead of `'${:,.2f}'.format`.

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values) you can change the format with the style accessor

```
df.style.format("{:.2%}")
```

Comment: I Ted, thanks for the quick respond I appreciate it! Your method works! But there's one thing that bothers me. I am trying to highlight the cells as well. Let's I want to highlight the max numbers in the data frame, but even I change the numbers to % format first. When I apply the highlight_max, the % format is gone.

Comment: Do you have any experience why this happens? And do you know how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: This works for me: `df.style.format("{:.2%}").highlight_max()`