# Customized float formatting in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have a `DataFrame`:

```
   0       1
0  3.000   5.600
1  1.200   3.456
```

and for presentation purposes I would like it to be converted to

```
   0    1
0  3    5.6
1  1.2  3.456
```

What is the elegant way to achieve this (without looping inefficiently over entries of the `DataFrame`)?

**Or perhaps more generally**: is there a way to set `pandas` up such that it is always doing this? E.g. one of the `pandas` options?

Notice that `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format` will not work, as it would give a fixed number of decimals, rather than having it vary across entries of the `DataFrame` as I indicated above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
In [188]: df
Out[188]:
       a      b       c
0 1.0000 2.2460  2.0000
1 3.0000 4.4920  6.0000
2 5.0000 6.7380 10.0000

In [189]: pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

In [190]: df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(int) if np.allclose(x, x.astype(int)) else x)
Out[190]:
   a    b   c
0  1 2.25   2
1  3 4.49   6
2  5 6.74  10
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [222]: df
Out[222]:
       0      1
0 3.0000 5.6000
1 1.2000 3.4560

In [223]: df.applymap(lambda x: str(int(x)) if abs(x - int(x)) < 1e-6 else str(round(x,2)))
Out[223]:
     0     1
0    3   5.6
1  1.2  3.46
```

**NOTE:** be aware that [.applymap()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) method is pretty slow as it's doing `map(func, series)` for each series in the DataFrame

Comment: You could format your data without changing its original value [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23922119/6829195)

Answer (score 14):

In case someone wants a quick way to apply the same precision to all numeric types in the dataframe (while not worrying about str types):

```
pd.set_option('display.precision', 2)
```

This works for displaying DataFrame and Styler objects in jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 8):

a simple method using round(), pass the number of digits you want to round to as a parameter.

Assuming that your DataFrame is named 'df':

```
df.round(2)
```

output:

```
   0     1
0  3.00  5.60
1  1.20  3.45
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It won't round the numbers.

Comment: At first, this wasn't working for. My df had string instead of numbers inside it.

Comment: @SteveGon glad it worked out. My first step ever is to use .info() method after loading-in the data set in order to identify and validate datatypes.

Answer (score 3):

A good solution for this to test whether the value has a decimal part and format it accordingly :

```
pd.options.display.float_format = lambda x : '{:.0f}'.format(x) if int(x) == x else '{:,.2f}'.format(x)
```

Edit: This will produce an error when NaNs are in your data. Consider instead using round():
`pd.options.display.float_format = lambda x : '{:.0f}'.format(x) if round(x,0) == x else '{:,.2f}'.format(x)`

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a modification of the answer that /u/SEDaradji gave, that *should* work even if there are NaNs or Infs

```
pd.options.display.float_format = lambda x : '{:,.2f}'.format(x) if (np.isnan(x) | np.isinf(x)) else '{:,.0f}'.format(x) if int(x) == x else '{:,.2f}'.format(x)
```

Comment: Is it safe to use `|` instead of `or` here?

Answer (score -1):

personally I recommend doing something like:

```
df['term'] = df['term'].apply(lambda term: int(term[:3]))
```

based on number