# Formatting numeric columns of a pandas data frame with a specified number of decimal digits

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I have to format a column of numbers in a data frame pandas rounding for two but with three decimal digits where the last is 0 and the column does not have to be a string. The numbers of this column must be represented so once exported to Excel.

```
d = {'col1': [0.567, 2.54765476], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

         col1  col2
0       0.567     3
1  2.54765476     4
```

expected:

```
    col1  col2
0  0.560     3
1  2.540     4
```

It is important that the type remain numerical

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customized float formatting in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735541/customized-float-formatting-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You sure `0,567` not `0.567`

Comment: is 0.567, It's a typo

Comment: Is it important to you that it be `2.540` and not `2.550` - ie truncating the float as opposed to rounding?

Comment: I have to round.

Answer (score 1):

You may need `floor` div then `format`

```
df.col1=(np.floor(df.col1*100)/100).map('{:,.3f}'.format)
df
Out[355]: 
    col1  col2
0  0.560     3
1  2.540     4
```

Comment: I had tried this solution but it is not good because map transforms the number into string.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, you need rounding rather than string truncation, then assuming your second value should be `2.550`, you can use Pandas float display options, as linked to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735541/customized-float-formatting-in-a-pandas-dataframe) by @G. Anderson:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.3f}'.format
df.col1 = df.col1.round(2)
df
>   
    col1    col2
0   0.570   3
1   2.550   4
```