# Pandas - Trying to make a new dataframe with counts and averages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataframe:

```
data = {'transit_time':[1,1,2,2,3,3],
        'orig_state':['UT','UT','UT','UT','UT','UT'],
        'dest_state':['CA','CA','AZ','AZ','NY','NY'],
        'GEOID':['01','01','02','02','03','03'],
        'dest_state_fn':['California','California','Arizona','Arizona','New York','New York'],
        'dest_county_name':['county1','county1','county2','county2','county3','county3']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['transit_time','orig_state','dest_state','GEOID','dest_state_fn','dest_county_name'])

print (df)

   transit_time orig_state dest_state GEOID dest_state_fn dest_county_name
0             1         UT         CA    01    California          county1
1             1         UT         CA    01    California          county1
2             2         UT         AZ    02       Arizona          county2
3             2         UT         AZ    02       Arizona          county2
4             3         UT         NY    03      New York          county3
5             3         UT         NY    03      New York          county3
```

I would like to get a dataframe that groups by GEOID, dest_county_name, AVG(transit time), COUNT(*) like the image below:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into the groupby function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check with `groupby` + `agg`

```
newdf=df.groupby(['GEOID','dest_county_name']).agg(ave_transit_time=('transit_time','mean'),
                                                   Count=('GEOID','count')).reset_index()

  GEOID dest_county_name  ave_transit_time  Count
0    01          county1                 1      2
1    02          county2                 2      2
2    03          county3                 3      2
```

Comment: getting error message back: "TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'"

Comment: @user2200270 what is your pandas version ?

Comment: @YOBBEN_S pd.__version__ = '0.24.2'

Comment: @user2200270 please update your pandas :-) after that you should be fine, tuple in agg adding in recent version :-)

Comment: @user2200270 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735541/customized-float-formatting-in-a-pandas-dataframe