# python float dot to comma with 2 decimals

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, etl

Im having a trouble here.

I have this data, "VALOR" is float:

| Periodo | VALOR |
| --- | --- |
| 32021 | 1096.14 |
| 32021 | 3835.44 |
| 32021 | 2207.90 |
| 32021 | 389.10 |

I'm trying to change dot to comma, and that ok.

But I need to save the 2 decimals, and when I convert it, it desappear when the last decimal is 0.

```py
df['VALOR'] = np.round(df['VALOR'], decimals=2).astype(str)
df['VALOR'] = df['VALOR'].str.replace('.',',')


df.head()
```

| Periodo | VALOR |
| --- | --- |
| 32021 | 1096,14 |
| 32021 | 3835,44 |
| 32021 | 2207,9 |
| 32021 | 389,1 |

How to get the 2 decimals here?

Regards,

Tanai

Comment: `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format`,  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735541/customized-float-formatting-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anurag
https://stackoverflow.com/users/14289892/anurag-dabas

This works

```py
df['VALOR']=df['VALOR'].apply(lambda x: '{:.2f},'.format(x))
df['VALOR'] = df['VALOR'].str.replace('.',',',regex=True)
df['VALOR']=df['VALOR'].str.rstrip(',')
```