# Formatting specific rows in a Jupyter Notebook dataframe output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm presenting a data frame in Jupyter Notebook. The initial data type of the data frame is float. I want to present rows 1 & 3 of the printed table as integers and rows 2 & 4 as percentage. How do I do that? (I've spent numerous hours looking for a solution with no success)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#Creating the table
clms = sales.columns
indx = ['# of Poeple','% of Poeple','# Purchased per Activity','% Purchased per Activity']
basic_stats = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan,index=indx,columns=clms)
basic_stats.head()

#Calculating the # of people who took part in each activity
for clm in sales.columns:
    basic_stats.iloc[0][clm] = int(round(sales[sales[clm]>0][clm].count(),0))

#Calculating the % of people who took part in each activity from the total email list
for clm in sales.columns:
    basic_stats.iloc[1][clm] = round((basic_stats.iloc[0][clm] / sales['Sales'].count())*100,2)

#Calculating the # of people who took part in each activity AND that bought the product
for clm in sales.columns:
    basic_stats.iloc[2][clm] = int(round(sales[(sales[clm] >0) & (sales['Sales']>0)][clm].count()))

#Calculating the % of people who took part in each activity AND that bought the product
for clm in sales.columns:
    basic_stats.iloc[3][clm] = round((basic_stats.iloc[2][clm] / basic_stats.iloc[0][clm])*100,2)

#Present the table
basic_stats
```

Here's the printed table:
[Output table of 'basic_stats' data frame in Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOTUR.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns)

Comment: I would recommend transposing your table, applying the solution to the suggested duplicate, then transposing back to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Integer representation

You already assign integers to the cells of row 1 and 3 are. The reason why these integers are printed as floats is that all columns have the data type `float64`. This is caused by the way you initially create the Dataframe. You can view the data types by printing the `.dtypes` attribute:

```
basic_stats = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan,index=indx,columns=clms)
print(basic_stats.dtypes)

# Prints:
# column1    float64
# column2    float64
# ...
# dtype: object
```

If you don't provide the `data` keyword argument in the constructor of the Data
frame, the data type of each cell will be `object` which can be any object:

```
basic_stats = pd.DataFrame(index=indx,columns=clms)
print(basic_stats.dtypes)

# Prints:
# column1    object
# column2    object
# ...
# dtype: object
```

When the data type of a cell is `object`, the content is formatted using it's builtin methods which leads to integers bein formatted properly.

## Percentage representation

In order to display percentages, you can use a custom class that prints a float number the way you want:

```
class PercentRepr(object):
    """Represents a floating point number as percent"""
    def __init__(self, float_value):
        self.value = float_value
    def __str__(self):
        return "{:.2f}%".format(self.value*100)
```

Then just use this class for the values of row 1 and 3:

```
#Creating the table
clms = sales.columns
indx = ['# of Poeple','% of Poeple','# Purchased per Activity','% Purchased per Activity']
basic_stats = pd.DataFrame(index=indx,columns=clms)
basic_stats.head()

#Calculating the # of people who took part in each activity
for clm in sales.columns:
    basic_stats.iloc[0][clm] = int(round(sales[sales[clm]>0][clm].count(),0))

#Calculating the % of people who took part in each activity from the total email list
for clm in sales.columns:
    basic_stats.iloc[1][clm] = PercentRepr(basic_stats.iloc[0][clm] / sales['Sales'].count())

#Calculating the # of people who took part in each activity AND that bought the product
for clm in sales.columns:
    basic_stats.iloc[2][clm] = int(round(sales[(sales[clm] >0) & (sales['Sales']>0)][clm].count()))

#Calculating the % of people who took part in each activity AND that bought the product
for clm in sales.columns:
    basic_stats.iloc[3][clm] = PercentRepr(basic_stats.iloc[2][clm] / basic_stats.iloc[0][clm])

#Present the table
basic_stats
```

Note: This actually changes the data in your dataframe! If you want to do further processing with the data of rows 1 and 3, you should be aware that these rows don't contain float objects anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very helpful solution and the important comment below. I learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, kind of a hack, but if its simply for pretty printing, it'll work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(20).reshape(4,5))

# first and third rows display as integers
df.loc[0,] = df.loc[0,]*100 
df.loc[2,] = df.loc[2,]*100

df.loc[0,:] = df.loc[0,:].astype(int).astype(str)
df.loc[2,:] = df.loc[2,:].astype(int).astype(str)

# second and fourth rows display as percents (with 2 decimals)
df.loc[1,:] = np.round(df.loc[1,:].values.astype(float),4).astype(float)*100
df.loc[3,:] = np.round(df.loc[3,:].values.astype(float),4).astype(float)*100
```