# Pandas : Want to covert Serial No. into full numbers

Tags: python, pandas

Guys please help to covert into the full int numbers this is a 16 digit numeric numbers

[Here is Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJyYI.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Please see for example [converting exponent or scientific number into integer in pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49836698/6734876) or [How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20937538/6734876).

I guess you want to do:

```
data['Serial No.'] = data['Serial No.'].astype(int)
```