# How do I customize the display format of a DataFrame with complex numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, complex-numbers

If I have a DataFrame of floats, I can customize the display using `pd.options.display.float_format`, as for example pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20937592/4063051). For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 2))
```

Which will give me the expected result:

[image]

On the other hand, if I try the same when the DataFrame contains *complex* floats, this doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 2) + 1j * np.random.randn(2, 2))
```

produces:

[image]

I don't see any specific mention of complex numbers in the [relevant docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html), and `'{:,.2f}'.format(np.complex(1.12345 + 1j * .8746234))` correctly truncates real and imaginary part of the complex number,
so why doesn't this work?

Comment: the datatype for complex number is `numpy.complex128` - maybe `pd.options.display.float_format` does not apply to this type

Comment: You may just have to use applymap to get the desired formatting.

Comment: @will7200 could you expand on that? Does that require to change the data in the dataframe? An example would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am new to python but, I found this and I like the output

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:,.0f}'.format)
```

In this option you can use the pd.set_option in order to get your desired output

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of obtaining the desired output using applymap, it will apply cell wise.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 2) + 1j * np.random.randn(2, 2)).applymap(lambda x: '{:,.2f}'.format(x))
```

Output:

```
            0            1
0  1.10-1.15j   0.49+0.65j
1  0.51+1.39j  -0.92-0.07j
```

Answer (score 0):

`display.float_format` does not work for complex numbers.

`display.precision` work for both floats and complex values.

e.g.: `pd.set_option("display.precision", 3))`