# In Pandas How To Invert Decimal Notation?

Tags: python, pandas, decimal-point

In python3 and pandas I have a dataframe with float values that are displayed like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df_despesas = pd.read_csv("resultados/despesas_dep_est_sp_julho.csv", sep=',',encoding = 'utf-8', converters={'CNPJ': lambda x: str(x), 'cnpj_raiz_fornecedor': lambda x: str(x), 'Ano': lambda x: str(x)}, decimal=',')

#Configuration to show float with two decimals
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format

df_despesas.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 455156 entries, 0 to 455155
Data columns (total 9 columns):
Ano                     455156 non-null object
CNPJ                    455156 non-null object
Deputado                455156 non-null object
Fornecedor              455156 non-null object
Matricula               455156 non-null object
Mes                     455156 non-null object
Tipo                    455156 non-null object
Valor                   455156 non-null float64
cnpj_raiz_fornecedor    455156 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(8)
memory usage: 31.3+ MB

df_despesas.reset_index().Valor.head()
0     200.00
1     295.40
2   2,850.00
3     100.00
4     195.01

"${:,.2f}".format(df_despesas.Valor.sum())
'$311,900,200.82'
```

I would like these numbers to appear with dot separating the thousands and comma the cents. Like this:

```
0     200,00
1     295,40
2   2.850,00
3     100,00
4     195,01

'$311.900.200,82'
```

Please, does anyone know how I should do it?

Comment: Isn't that `{:n}` in an appropriate locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to achieve what you are looking for, i.e. `dot separating the thousands and comma the cents` would be to use string manipulation. You can create a new function to do so and then use `apply` to apply it on the respective dataframe column

```
x = [200, 295.40, 2850, 100, 195.01]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["value"])
df.value = df.value.map('{:,.2f}'.format)
df
      value
0    200.00
1    295.40
2  2,850.00
3    100.00
4    195.01
```

now create a function to change dots to commas and commas to dots and apply it to the dataframe column

```
def change_format(x):
    return str(x).replace('.', '/').replace(',', '.').replace('/', ',')

df.value = df.value.apply(change_format)
df  
      value
0    200,00
1    295,40
2  2.850,00
3    100,00
4    195,01
```

Comment: Thank you. But in that case the column will turn into string, right? My intention was to show in a reverse notation and still allow the float format to do math operations. It seems to me then that Python only accepts the dotted notation separating the decimals

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves: yeah the column would be of "Object". Btw,  I don't think it would be possible in python (or maybe in any other language) to perform math operations like that, but hopefully my solution helps you to in some way.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered here:

[How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns)

From the comment there, I see that you can simply do

```
df_despesas['Valor_dollars_fmt'] = df_despesas['Valor'].map('${:,.2f}'.format)
```