# Pandas get decimal fractional number part from float in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, floating-point

**How to extract the decimal number part from a float (float64) in a dataframe?** (a very common scenario but I can 't find a solution in StackOverFlow)

Note: be careful with the `196.09`, I need `09`, not `9`.

Sample DataFrame:

```
    dollars Count
0   56.46   2
1   196.09  3
2   78.12   2
```

Expected result is the 2 decimal digits:

```
    decimal
0   46
1   09
2   12
```

Comment: Just because you want leading-zero padding on the result, you don't want `09` returned for `196.09`. You could either have a string result (not an int, slow, can't do further arithmetic on it), or (better) you can use an int result, just remember to use `f'{number:02d}'` or `'{:02d}'.format` when you display it. Or simply set `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:02d}'.format`, or see [How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Alternative 1**

An alternative would be to convert `dollars` to string, then use a regex to extract everything after the `.`:

```
df['decimal'] = df.dollars.astype(str).str.extract('\.(.*)').astype(int)

>>> df
   dollars  Count  decimal
0    56.46      2       46
1   196.69      3       69
2    78.12      2       12
```

**Alternative 2**

Or, you could subtract `dollars` from the `int` part of dollars, and multiply by 100:

```
df['decimal'] = (df.dollars.sub(df.dollars.astype(int))).mul(100).astype(int)

>>> df
   dollars  Count  decimal
0    56.46      2       46
1   196.69      3       68
2    78.12      2       12
```

---

**Edit**: based on the edit to OP's question, it seems that the decimal parts need to be displayed to 2 decimal points (*e.g.* it would need to be `09` instead of `9`). In this case, It has to be displayed as a string, and not an `int`. The first method I outlined above would still work if you omit `astype(int)`:

```
df['decimal'] = df.dollars.astype(str).str.extract('\.(.*)')

>>> df
   dollars  Count decimal
0    56.46      2      46
1   196.09      3      09
2    78.12      2      12
```

Or, this could be done after the fact using `zfill`, if we already have the decimal part as an int:

```
df['decimal'] = df['decimal'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Comment: i made a small change to 196.69,  if i have 196.09, I need 09, not 9, how to solve it?

Comment: See my edits. It has to be displayed as a string in that case

Answer (score 7):

Use [`numpy.modf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html), multiple by `100` and cast to `integer`s:

```
df['decimal'] = (np.modf(df['dollars'])[0] * 100).astype(int)
```

Or `split` by `.`:

```
df['decimal'] = df['dollars'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[1].astype(int)

print (df)
   dollars  Count  decimal
0    56.46      2       46
1   196.69      3       68
2    78.12      2       12
```

EDIT: If need `09` format need second solution - output is `string`s:

```
df['decimal'] = df['dollars'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[1]
print (df)
   dollars  Count decimal
0    56.46      2      46
1   196.09      3      09
2    78.12      2      12
```

Comment: i made a small change to 196.69,  if i have 196.09, I need 09, not 9, how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

If you know you have 2 decimal places.. just use `%` broadcasting

```
s = df.dollars % 1 * 100

0    46.0
1    69.0
2    12.0
Name: dollars, dtype: float64

s.astype(int)

0    46
1    69
2    12
```