# How can you use math.modf in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point, modulo

I understand that math.modf returns a string because it is a wrapper around C language standard but it means I am getting the error `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>` when I try to add the float number as a column to my dataframe. Here is my code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('scandi_short.csv', error_bad_lines=False, 
                  names=['Bloomberg Code', 'index', 'Bid Price', 'Ask Price', 'Trade Price','Bid Volume','Ask Volume','Trade Volume','Update type','Change to Ask','Date','Time in seconds past midnight','Opening price','Condition codes','na','na2'])
dataset['Trade price float'] = int(math.modf(dataset['Trade Price']))
print(dataset)
```

As you can see I have tried making the math.modf function an integer but I still get the same error, please help!

Comment: You need to apply the math.modf in a per element basis, to the series, use apply

Comment: Use `df.apply` which is same as `map` used on a DataFrame

Comment: brilliant this works. now can you help me to get rid of the whole so I only keep the fraction? I am using `dataset['Trade price float'] = dataset['Trade Price'].apply(math.modf)` but I dont want (0.4000000000000057, 123.0) I just want the first part

Comment: The [`math.modf`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=math.modf#math.modf) doc clearly says **it returns a tuple of two signed floats `(fractional_part, integer_part)`**. Not a string. And if you only want the integer part, you could slice [0], but really you don't even need `modf`, you can just do .`astype(int)`

Comment: Related, near-duplicate: [Pandas get decimal fractional number part from float in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638367/pandas-get-decimal-fractional-number-part-from-float-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: One-line answer: a) **don't use `math.modf` on a dataframe, use `np.modf`, it's vectorized**.  b) But in your case, `int(modf(df['Price']))` is **just an obfuscation for `df['Price'].astype(int)`**. (If you did use `modf()`, you'd only slice `[0]` to get the integer part and throw away the fractional part, anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error: `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>` is because you are passing a Series to `math.modf`, so you need to either...

#### a) [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) the function to each element of the Series:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1.5, 2.3, 4.0])

res = s.apply(math.modf)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0                   (0.5, 1.0)
1    (0.2999999999999998, 2.0)
2                   (0.0, 4.0)
dtype: object
```

or:

#### b) better use [`numpy.modf`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html), which is vectorized:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1.5, 2.3, 4.0])

res_np = pd.Series(zip(*np.modf(s)))
print(res_np)
```

**Output**

```
0                   (0.5, 1.0)
1    (0.2999999999999998, 2.0)
2                   (0.0, 4.0)
dtype: object
```

#### c) UPDATE: If you only need the first (integer) part, you can do:

```
res = s.apply(lambda x: math.modf(x)[0])
print(res)

res_np, _ = np.modf(s)
print(res_np)
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @JohnSonnino I just tested the code, make sure you copied correctly

Comment: so sorry but I am getting this error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` when I try to take the first item

Comment: what do  need to do to this? `dataset['Trade price float'] = dataset['Trade Price'].apply(math.modf)[0]` it doesnt seem to like the index at the end

Comment: @JohnSonnino Use the numpy version is faster and easier to use, otherwise, you need to do `dataset['Trade price float'] = dataset['Trade Price'].apply(lambda x: math.modf(x)[0])`