# Add '+' sign to positive numbers in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a "+" to all positive values in my df.

Here is my df

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-1,3,0,5],
                   'B':[4,5,6,5],
                   'C':[8,-9,np.nan,7]})

print (df)
   A  B    C
0 -1  4  8.0
1  3  5 -9.0
2  0  6  NaN
3  5  5  7.0
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
print (df)
   A  B    C
0 -1  +4  +8.0
1  +3  +5 -9.0
2  +0  +6  NaN
3  +5  +5  +7.0
```

My attempt:

```
df[df > 0] = "+"
```

That just replaced the positive values with "+"

Comment: you have to change the data to `str` if you want to have preceding`+` sign.

Comment: Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns

Comment: Note: It will change your dtype, which is risk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: "+"+str(x) if x>0 else x)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A   B     C
0  -1  +4  +8.0
1  +3  +5    -9
2   0  +6   NaN
3  +5  +5  +7.0
```

Answer (score 6):

Use display options instead of converting your floats as strings (which is NOT what you want) :

Example :

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:+,.2f}'.format
pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.2, -3.4]})
```

Returns :

```
    a
0   +1.20
1   -3.40
```

---

**EDIT**

Better solution imo : you can use [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) to change the format of one or multiple columns of your dataframe

Example :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, -3], 'b': ['Hello', 'World'], 'c': [1.234, -1.3]})
df.style.format({'a':'{:+d}', 'c': '{:+g}'})
```

Returns :

```
    a   b       c
0   +1  Hello   +1.234
1   -3  World   -1.3
```

---

For your specific dataframe, you can do :

```
df.style.format('{:+g}')
```

Returns

```
     A  B   C
0   -1  +4  +8
1   +3  +5  -9
2   +0  +6  +nan
3   +5  +5  +7
```

If you want to remove the `+nan`, you can do :

```
df.style.format(lambda x:  'NaN' if np.isnan(x) else '{:+g}'.format(x))
```

Returns

```
     A   B   C
0   -1  +4  +8
1   +3  +5  -9
2   +0  +6  NaN
3   +5  +5  +7
```

Comment: @MedAli - I think instead of converting into str, converting to float will be better approach

Comment: @MohamedThasinah, thank you, I edited because I think you should never convert types only for formatting.

Comment: @CorentinLimier -  It's more flexible way to deal this problem :-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!