# Combine duplicate rows on specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine rows of a dataframe in the event that there is a duplicate in one column. The dataframe looks like the following.

```
Name   Code   X   Y
 A     123   10   11
 B     456   12   13
 C     123   15   16
```

I want to combine on Code. So if the Code is the same, combine the other data separated by a comma. The resulting df would look like this:

```
Name   Code    X       Y
A,C    123   10,15   11,16
 B     456    12       13
```

My approach was the following:

```
    df = df.groupby(['Name','Code','Y'])['X'].astype(str).apply(', '.join).reset_index() 

    df = df.groupby(['Name','Code','X'])['Y'].astype(str).apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

I get the following error :

```
"Cannot access callable attribute 'astype' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"
```

I have been unable to figure out how to use apply to cast as type str, any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another layout

```
(df.set_index('Code').astype(str)+',').sum(level=0).apply(lambda x : x.str.strip(','))
Out[50]: 
     Name      X      Y
Code                   
123   A,C  10,15  11,16
456     B     12     13
```

Comment: Why would this cause a number like '0.007' to become '0.00699999999' after running it? For some reason every solution offered changes the numbers after combining them.

Comment: @MaxB that is the problem with pandas , if that is the case , format you float number first :-)

Comment: is there something I should do before calling this? Or attempt to round the numbers after? Rounding doesn't seem like it will solve my problem completely.

Comment: @MaxB I mean something like df['float col']=df['float col'].map('${:,.3f}'.format)

Comment: Hmm. I then get the error 'Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str''

Comment: @MaxB let me show your the link . :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns

Answer (score 5):

Create index from `Code` column fo avoid casting to strings, then cast all columns and aggregate by index function `join`:

```
df = df.set_index('Code').astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join).reset_index()
#pandas 0.24+
#df = df.set_index('Code').astype(str).groupby('Code').agg(', '.join).reset_index()
print (df)
   Code  Name       X       Y
0   123  A, C  10, 15  11, 16
1   456     B      12      13
```

Answer (score 1):

More general solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',123,10,11],['B',456,12,13],['C',123,15,16]],columns=['Name','Code','X','Y'])

def f(x):
    return ','.join(x)

df = df.astype(str).groupby('Code').agg(f)
df.index = [int(i) for i in df.index.tolist()]
```

The last line changes the index from `string` back to `integer` type. 
I added this solution because it is easy to understand, however not the most elegant.

Comment: This is my original solution, problem is column `Code` is casted to strings

Comment: df.index = [int(i) for i in df.index.tolist()]