# How to update format of string before & after decimal by given padding value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, format

**Desire format:**

`CODE: "0700.1707300","2700.1707380","0060.1500000","3400.1600215"`

**Dataset**:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({"CODE": 
["700.17073","2700.170738","60.150","3400.1600215"}) # dtype('float64')
```

**Example**:

```
IN: '{:012.7f}'.format(700.17073) 
OUT: '0700.1707300' <-- return desire format
```

**Problem**:
`CODE.rjust,CODE.ljust` convert only one part before / after decimal of the index. 
OR
**Getting error by this script :**

```
dt["CODE"].loc[dt["CODE"].'{:012.7f}'.format()]
```

**In R data.table:**

```
dt[,CODE:=formatC(as.numeric(CODE), format = 'f', width = 12, flag = '0', digits = 7)] <-- can achieve by formatC
```

How to update this column from `dtype('float64')` into desire formatting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns)

Comment: Georgy thanks for sharing the link but its not changing the index , just displaying in different format  ?(`print df.to_string(formatters={'cost':'${:,.2f}'.format})
`) also , where is the answer from the question tells how to add fixed value (like: 0) before decimal ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved :**

```
df['CODE'] = df['CODE'].map('{:012.7f}'.format)
```