# Python - Error when trying to groupby year and summarize sales data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I've got a dataset of transactions that i'm trying to summarize by year but  when i run the output is the individual amounts by transaction.  I've imported a csv into into python using pd.read_csv and cleaned up a few of the columns in the dataframe as well as adding new ones.

I'm using the following code that's generating the output below

```
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df.groupby(df['Year'])['revenue'].agg(['sum'])

OUTPUT
    Year                                       Sum
    2015      1203.21 1732.12 2551.01 1733.12 1323.44
    2016      3203.21 1532.12 4431.01 1433.12 7323.44
    2017      2203.21 122.12 131.01 1293.12 4223.44
    2018      6203.21 232.12 1131.01 1533.12 4323.44
```

I have the following line of code to convert 'revenue' from string to float

```
pd.to_numeric(df['revenue'])
```

Year, Date and revenue are all columns in my dataframe.  I want to be able to have one total for each year above as opposed to seeing the value of the individual transactions.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `df[['Year', 'revenue']].head()`? It looks like you are summing strings.

Comment: The output is the values of the first four transactions for the first year of data. 

I updated the original question to include the code i have converting the string to float

Comment: To see if it might be a string for the revenues, try: `df.groupby('Year')['revenue'].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip().astype(float).sum())`. If that works, that you should first convert the `revenue` column to floats before applying the `groupby`.

Comment: I think you are close, only is necessary assign - `df['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['revenue'])` and then `df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df.groupby(df['Year'])['revenue'].agg(['sum'])
`

Comment: Thanks Jezrael.  That works.
Alexander, is the code you are proposing converting the revenue to a float if it were an string?

Comment: @wolfblitza Yes, I was proposing you first transform the revenue via `df['revenue'] = df['revenue'].astype(float)`, but it appears that you have now figured that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign back output of [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) function, because not working inplace:

```
df['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['revenue'])
```

Alternative solution:

```
df['revenue'] = df['revenue'].astype(float)
```

---

```
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year 
df1 = df.groupby('Year', as_index=False)['revenue'].sum()
```

If want one line solution:

```
df1=pd.to_numeric(df['revenue']).groupby(df['Date'].dt.year.rename('Year')).sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: the solution is appearing in exponents to the power of 6 and 7 since i'm dealing with numbers in the millions.  I removed all of the commas and dollar signs when converting to float but how would i add them back in.

Comment: @wolfblitza - Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20937592)?

Comment: Thanks. That helped.

Answer (score 0):

The code proposed by Jezrael above works as intended. 
I was using `pd.to_numeric(df['revenue'])` but have now changed it to `df['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['revenue'])`