# In Python how can I format a pandas dataframe and crosstab?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
cols= ['DD','MM','YYYY','HH'] #names
DD,MM,YYYY,HH=[1,2,None,4,5,5],[1,1,1,2,2,3],[2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014],[20,20,20,18,18,18] #data
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(DD,MM,YYYY,HH)), columns =cols )
print (df)
a=pd.crosstab(df .HH, df .MM,margins=True)
print (a)
```

I would like to view results in a table format. Table borders or at least the same number of digits would solve the problem.
I want to see the table on console without any graphical window.

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research and the [pandas styling documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)? And what was the result?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, mr. @G.Anderson. But with this page only relates to highlihts and so on.

Comment: How about [How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns)

Comment: IIUC, `display()`, is it like what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nicely looking crosstab you can use [seaborn.heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)

An example

```
>>> import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
>>> import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
>>> uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
>>> ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
```

result would look like this:

[image]

You can find many examples that show how to apply this, e.g.:

- https://www.science-emergence.com/Codes/How-to-plot-a-confusion-matrix-with-matplotlib-and-seaborn/
- https://gist.github.com/shaypal5/94c53d765083101efc0240d776a23823

### Update

In order to simply display the crosstab in a formatted way you can skip the `print` and display like this

```
import pandas as pd
cols= ['DD','MM','YYYY','HH'] #names
DD,MM,YYYY,HH=[1,2,None,4,5,5],[1,1,1,2,2,3],[2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2014],[20,20,20,18,18,18] #data
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(DD,MM,YYYY,HH)), columns =cols )
print (df)
a = pd.crosstab(df .HH, df .MM,margins=True)
display(a)
```

which will yield the same result as:

```
pd.crosstab(df .HH, df .MM,margins=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this solution would create a plot. I want rather a table format in the pandas or pretty table style. So one can see results in the console.

Comment: How about just running pd.crosstab() without using print() ?