# Python Number Formatting in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, format, rounding, precision

I am putting together a table (var_sig in the code below) of p-values but I cannot get the numbers to show in 4 decimal places. I tried the map function, but it returned the error message "Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'. Then I tried wrapping pval in float() but that also returned an error. How can I fix the code below?

```
insdf = pd.DataFrame({'n':[500,1200,100,400,500,300],
                     'c':[42, 37, 1, 101, 73, 14],
                     'car':['small','medium','large','small','medium','large'],
                     'age':[1,1,1,2,2,2]})
insdf['n_log']=np.log(insdf['n'])
ratingvar = ['car','age']
def glm_freq(df, family, ratingvar, exposure, response, offset):  
    h2o.no_progress()
    hf = h2o.H2OFrame(df)    
    # first convert to categorical variables
    print('***Rebasing levels***')
    for r in ratingvar:
        hf[r] = hf[r].asfactor()
    # then re-basing on level with most exposure
        rebase = pd.pivot_table(df, 
                                values=[exposure], 
                                index=[r], 
                                aggfunc=np.sum).sort_values((exposure), ascending=False).index.to_list()
        rebase_list = [str(x) for x in rebase]
        hf[r] = hf[r].set_levels(levels=rebase_list)

    print('***Fitting GLM***')
    glm_model = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family= family,
                                              lambda_ = 0,
                                              compute_p_values = True,
                                              offset_column = offset
                                             )
    glm_model.train(ratingvar, response, training_frame= hf)
    print('***Printing model diagnostics***')
    print('Model AIC is: ', glm_model.aic())
    print('Model Residual Deviance is: ', glm_model.residual_deviance())
    llf = glm_model.scoring_history()['negative_log_likelihood'].iloc[-1]
    print('Log Likelihood is: ', llf)
    
    print('***Calculating Type III Statistics***')
    var_sig=pd.DataFrame(columns=['ratingvar','pval'])    
    for p in ratingvar:
        remainder_pred = ratingvar.copy()
        remainder_pred.remove(p)
        glm_model_tmp = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family= family,
                                              lambda_ = 0,
                                              compute_p_values = True, 
                                              offset_column = offset
                                             )        
        glm_model_tmp.train(remainder_pred, response, training_frame = hf)    
        llvar = glm_model_tmp.scoring_history()['negative_log_likelihood'].iloc[-1]            
        d_freedom = df[p].unique().shape[0] - 1
        print('Degree of freedom of ', str(p), ' is ', d_freedom)
        chisqstat = 2 * (llvar - llf)        
        print('Log Likelihood of model without ', str(p), ' is ', llvar)
        print('Chi-sq stat of ', str(p), ' is ', chisqstat)        
        pval = 1-stats.chi2.cdf(chisqstat, d_freedom)
        var_sig = var_sig.append({'ratingvar':p,'pval':pval}, ignore_index=True)
        var_sig['pval'] = var_sig['pval'].map('{:.4f}'.format)

    return var_sig
glm_freq(insdf, 'poisson', ratingvar, 'n', 'c', 'n_log')
```

Comment: it might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns

Comment: Thanks - but as you can see in my code I already tried that and it didn't work

Comment: Hi, it seems there's a lot of code going on here that doesn't really need to be here. If you may share a [mcve], people here might help you better. In essence, "I have this, I want this, I tried this, I get this" but minimally and in a reproducible manner.

Comment: please share a sample of the dataframe contains the column you want to extract the decimal number (with the right type)

Comment: I can do that, but I am not sure if the dataframe is exactly in the same format as the one reproduced by my code above.

Comment: A simple reproduction would be var_sig = pd.DataFrame({'var':['age','car'], 'pval':[0.2543,0.0432]}

Comment: Again I am not sure if the number format is exactly the same as the one reproduced above. I suspect somewhere along the way my numbers are converted into strings, which is why I reproduced the code in its entirety. Hope you understand.