# Add commas to decimal column without rounding off

Tags: python, dataframe, decimal

I have pandas column named **Price_col**. which look like this.

```
       Price_col
    1. 1000000.000
    2. 234556.678900
    3. 2345.00
    4.
    5. 23.56
```

I am trying to add commas to my Price_col to look like this.

```
       Price_col
    1. 1,000,000.000
    2. 234,556.678900
    3. 2,345.00
    4.
    5. 23.56
```

when I try convert the values it always round off. is there way that I can have original value without rounding off.

I tried below code. this what I got for the value 234556.678900.

```
n = "{:,}".format(234556.678900)
print(n)
>>> 234,556.6789
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `f` for fixed-point

```py
>>> "{:,}".format(234556.678900)
'234,556.6789'
>>> "{:,f}".format(234556.678900)
'234,556.678900'
```

You can also control the precision with `.p` where p is the number of digits (and should probably do so) .. *beware*, as you're dealing with floats, you'll have some [IEEE 754 aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), though representation via format should be quite nice regardless of the backing data

```py
>>> "{:,.5f}".format(234556.678900)
'234,556.67890'
>>> "{:,.20f}".format(234556.678900)
'234,556.67889999999897554517'
```

The full **Format Specification Mini-Language** can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Comment: Thankyou so much is there a way that I can apply this for a entire column in a single statement without looping through and changing value one by one.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I realized you may really want something else as described in [How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns) and only change the *view* of the data

Creating a new *string* column formatted as a string

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Price_col": [1000000.000, 234556.678900, 2345.00, None, 23.56]}
>>> df["price2"] = df["Price_col"].apply(lambda x: f"{x:,f}")
>>> df
      Price_col            price2
0  1000000.0000  1,000,000.000000
1   234556.6789    234,556.678900
2     2345.0000      2,345.000000
3           NaN               nan
4       23.5600         23.560000
>>> df.dtypes
Price_col    float64
price2        object
dtype: object
```

Temporarily changing how data is displayed

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Price_col": [1000000.000, 234556.678900, 2345.00, None, 23.56]}
>>> print(df)
      Price_col
0  1000000.0000
1   234556.6789
2     2345.0000
3           NaN
4       23.5600
>>> with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '€{:>18,.6f}'.format):
...     print(df)
... 
            Price_col
0 €  1,000,000.000000
1 €    234,556.678900
2 €      2,345.000000
3                 NaN
4 €         23.560000
>>> print(df)
      Price_col
0  1000000.0000
1   234556.6789
2     2345.0000
3           NaN
4       23.5600
```