# Formatting Multiple Columns by Name using .loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to state a list of columns by name that I want to apply the formatting to.

The section that is commented out is ideally what I am after (which would mean removing the line of code directly above what is commented), but I get the following error:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'` error.
```

Is there a way/better way to achieve what I am attempting?

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Spend', 'Sales']
stuff=[[3, 2],[5, 6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(stuff, columns = cols)


df.loc[:, 'Spend'] ='$'+ df['Spend'].map('{:,.0f}'.format)

# list1=['Spend', 'Sales']
# df.loc[:, list1] ='$'+ df[list1].map('{:,.0f}'.format)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code almost gets there, you just need to call `map` inside a call to `apply` (which will do it for each column):

```
list1 = ['Spend', 'Sales']
df.loc[:, list1] = '$'+ df[list1].apply(lambda col: col.map('{:,.0f}'.format))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Spend Sales
0    $3    $2
1    $5    $6
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a method to do this with vecotrization?

Comment: No. However, if you're thinking that `apply` is slow (as they always say), you're right that it is, **but**, since it's being used for each *column* rather than each *row*, it's not really a concern here. Using `apply` for each column is generally considered fine.

Comment: @anarchocaps `apply` on `axis=0` is actually very fast. For a DataFrame of shape `(200000, 2)`, it's the fastest option given here; it's ~7% faster than @@bertwassink's answer and ~15% faster than my answer

Comment: Or use a list comprehension. There is no vectorization per se for strings (maybe with arrow strings), so list comprehension should be fast enough

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something along the lines of:

```
df[list1] =['$']*2 + df[list1].astype(str)
```

or ([as suggested by @richardec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71623452/formatting-multiple-columns-by-name-using-loc/71623482#comment126584270_71623482)):

```
df[list1] = '$' + df[list1].astype(str)
```

Output:

```
  Spend Sales
0    $3    $2
1    $5    $6
```

Comment: `['$']*2` is not *necessary*, you can just use `$`

Comment: This is nice, but is there also a way to make it work with something like df.loc[:, list1'] = df[list1].map('{:,.0f}'.format)  ?  the formatting I am doing does not always simply add a character on the front or back. ty

Answer (score 2):

From this thread [How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns) we can learn

```py
cols = ['Spend', 'Sales']
stuff=[[3, 2],[5, 6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(stuff, columns = cols)
list1 = ['Spend', 'Sales']
df[list1] = df[list1].applymap('${:,.2f}'.format)
```

output

```
df
   Spend  Sales
0  $3.00  $2.00
1  $5.00  $6.00
```

Comment: Using `applymap` here is cool! However, it's not as vectized as would be using `apply`-columnwise + `map`, as in my answer. +1 soon anyway

Comment: It is indeed not optimal, but you might want to include the dollar sign as a function argument if you want to pipe several functions.

Comment: @richardec, _'it's not as vectized as would be using apply'_, maybe it's not as vectorized but definetly faster - 2.07 ms ± 52.3 µs against 2.6 ms ± 59.3 µs. Anyway [@enke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71623482/18344512) solution even more faster - 1.11 ms ± 19.3 µs

Comment: @SergFSM interesting! Wouldn't have guessed that.

Comment: It is probably because it is a small example. I guess there will be turning point after which the vectorized solution will be perform better. This is usually the case for vectorized solutions.