# Python Machine Learning value in e form instead of integer or float

Tags: python, pandas

When i am running this code the predicted values come out to be in the form of e(6.291149e+06,5.684170e+06)

```
pred_y_df=pd.DataFrame({'Actual Value':y_test,'Predicted value':y_pred,'Difference':y_test-y_pred})
pred_y_df[0:20]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/einVd.png)

```
    Actual Value    Predicted value Difference
136 5740000 6.291149e+06    -5.511488e+05
80  6629000 5.684170e+06    9.448304e+05
47  7490000 7.709115e+06    -2.191149e+05
526 2310000 2.587718e+06    -2.777181e+05
200 4900000 4.867998e+06    3.200241e+04
527 2275000 2.417865e+06    -1.428652e+05
278 4277000 5.021664e+06    -7.446643e+05
402 3500000 3.228685e+06    2.713153e+05
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I am getting the value in form of e
6.291149e+06 like that i want these value to be in int or float

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line before you are displaying the results:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format
```

Alternatively, you can format the actual columns, e.g.:

```
pred_y_df['Predicted'] = pred_y_df['Predicted'].map('${:,.2f}'.format)
```

Comment: It show the below error
```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-5832e93371f0> in <module>()
      1 #y_pred=model.predict(np.array([x_test]).reshape(-1,1))
----> 2 y_pred=model.predict(x_test.values).map('${:,.2f}'.format)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Comment: @SparshMaheshwari - you need to apply the .map on the datadframe, i.e. after you transform it to a dataframe using pd.DataFrame