# Automatically format pandas table without changing data

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to format the output of a particular column of a panda's data frame (e.g., as currency, with `${:,.2f}`, or percentage, with `{:,.2%}`) without changing the data itself?

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns?newreg=42508ba35d2a42a096b82e72bd372863) I see that `map` can be used, but it changes the data to strings.

I also see that I can use `.style.format` (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html)) to print a data frame with some formatting, but it returns a `Styler` object.

I would like just to change the default print out of the data frame itself, so that it always print it formatted as specified. (I suppose this means changing `__repr__` or `__repr_html__`.)  I'd assume that there is a simple way of doing this in pandas, but I could not find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT (for clarification):** Suppose I have a data frame `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Price": [1234.5, 3456.789], "Increase": [0.01234, 0.23456]})
```

I want the column `Price` to be formatted with `"${:,.2f}"` and column `Increase` to be formatted with `"{:,.2%}"` whenever I print `df` in a Jupyter notebook (with `print` or just running a cell ending in `df`).

I can use

```py
df.style.format({"Price": "${:,.2f}", "Increase": "{:,.2%}"})
```

but I do not want to type that every time I print `df`.

I could also do

```py
df["Price"] = df["Price"].map("${:,.2f}".format)
df["Increase"] = df["Increase"].map("{:,.2%}".format)
```

which *does* always print as I want (with `print(df)`), but this changes the columns from `float64` to `object`, so I cannot manipulate the data frame anymore.

Comment: I think you missed the first part of the [first answer](/a/20937592/15497888) which uses `pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format` that does not alter data at all. Or the [second answer](/a/23922119/15497888) which uses formatters for a specific column only with `.to_string(formatters={'cost':'${:,.2f}'.format})`

Comment: What do you mean change the default print of the DataFrame itself? If you're only looking to select specific columns to format how do you specify which columns get formatted this way, if you're not looking to change all float columns uniformly like in Q & A you linked?

Comment: I do not want to change the default printing of floats, as I want to apply formatting to specific columns.  By the "default print out of the data frame", I mean if I just print the data frame itself, like `print(df)` (or having `df` as last line of a Jupyter notebook cell), it will print the formatted version, according to some specified format (for specific column(s)).  I would prefer not to use formatting commands every time I print the data frame to obtain the formatted version.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to overload/monkey patch a pandas DataFrame instead just making a `print_df` function that calls `print(df.to_string(...))`?

Comment: Just "ease of use".  I assumed there was a good and proper way of doing this, as it seems a very natural feature.  I can live with `to_string` if there is no good/proper solution.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is a natural feature, but pandas cannot guess what your format is, and each time you create a styler it has to be informed of such decisions, since it is a separate object. It does not dynamically update if you change your DataFrame.

The best you can do is to create a generic `print` via styler.

```py
def p(df):
    styler = dy.style
    styler.format({"Price": "${:,.2f}", "Increase": "{:,.2%}"})
    return styler

df = DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=["Price", "Increase"])
p(df)
```