# Formatting of numbers in Pandas dataframes - use % in format but not change to string?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a df element that is a float that is .125.  I can format this as percent so that it is displayed as 12.5% when printing the df or parts of the df, but this seems to change that dataframe element to a string that is "12.5%".  Is that correct that the type of the element has changed from float to string?  This has implications as I can no longer do math operations as this is no longer a number.

Is there any way to preserve this element as a float but just change the related formatting property of this dataframe element?

Think of excel. You can have cell B12 with the value 125.  If you change the formatting this could be displayed as 12.5%, 1/8, 0.125000, or $0.125, or other ways, but it is still considered a number, not text and I can still perform math operations on this cell.

Is there anything analagous in dataframes, or a way to more easily deal with formatting of numbers in dataframes so that you can change the display format, but not change the type of the underlying element (or series)?

To be able to change the format of a number and not have it change to a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display pandas DataFrame of floats using a format string for columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937538/how-to-display-pandas-dataframe-of-floats-using-a-format-string-for-columns)

Comment: It looks like the context manager may work, as in "with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '${:,.2f}'.format):
    display(df)"
But I want to format different coluuns/rows with different styles so I don't know that you can do that with this solution.

Comment: How about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370761/15704972) to that question? `DataFrame.style.format` can be applied e.g. per column.

Answer (score 0):

Does the below help? input_data is the name of df. The details enclosed in curly parenthesis dictate the decimals displayed. 'perc' is the name of column i apply the format to. This will just display the column as percentage without changing underlying column type. Is this what you are looking for?

```
input_data.style.format('{:.2%}',subset=['perc'])
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for.  I will give it a try.