# Converting Float to Dollars and Cents

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, string-formatting, currency

First of all, I have tried this post (among others): [Currency formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python).  It has no affect on my variable.  My best guess is that it is because I am using Python 3 and that was code for Python 2.  (Unless I overlooked something, because I am new to Python).

**I want to convert a float, such as 1234.5, to a String, such as "$1,234.50".  How would I go about doing this?**

And just in case, here is my code which compiled, but did not affect my variable:

```
money = float(1234.5)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
locale.currency(money, grouping=True)
```

Also unsuccessful:

```
money = float(1234.5)
print(money) #output is 1234.5
'${:,.2f}'.format(money)
print(money) #output is 1234.5
```

Comment: The latter option works in both Python 2.7 and 3.3.

Comment: does not appear to work, as discussed in your answer

Comment: Something else is going on with your code. Can you post more of the context?

Comment: k i posted updated version. any ideas?

Comment: Ah, you need to assign money (or a new variable) to '${:,.2f}'.format(money). For example, try money = '${:,.2f}'.format(money), and then print out money.

Comment: got it. need to set the format() to a new string variable! thanks!

Comment: Great. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

In Python 3.x and 2.7, you can simply do this:

```
>>> '${:,.2f}'.format(1234.5)
'$1,234.50'
```

The `:,` adds a comma as a thousands separator, and the `.2f` limits the string to two decimal places (or adds enough zeroes to get to 2 decimal places, as the case may be) at the end.

Comment: '${:,.2f}'.format(money) after money = float(1234.5) has no affect.  Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @Evorlor Yes, that works for me in both Python 3.3 and 2.7. Did you assign money to a variable that you need to print out?

Comment: yes i did and have confirmed that by printing money before and after

Comment: @Evorlor can you post the rest of the context of your code? This does really work. See the docs [here for more explanation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html).

Comment: This doesn't work for negative values.  '${:,.2f}'.format(-2) returns '$-2.00'.  locale.currency(-2, grouping=True) returns '-$2.00'.  Just import locale and call locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

Comment: locale works, but this also works in python3: ` (money<0)*'-' + '${:,.2f}'.format(money)`.

Answer (score 19):

In python 3, you can use:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'English_United States.1252' )
locale.currency( 1234.50, grouping = True )
```

Output

```
'$1,234.50'
```

Comment: `locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US' )`

Comment: @bparker looks like Windows fails to follow POSIX standard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)
My previous comment was for linux/mac. I'm sorry I forgot to mention this detail.

Answer (score 17):

Building on @JustinBarber's example and noting @eric.frederich's comment, if you want to format negative values like `-$1,000.00` rather than `$-1,000.00` and don't want to use `locale`:

```
def as_currency(amount):
    if amount >= 0:
        return '${:,.2f}'.format(amount)
    else:
        return '-${:,.2f}'.format(-amount)
```

Comment: Nice... which got me thinking about doing this in a pinch without a def... boolean slicing... "{}${:,.2f}".format(["","-"][amount<0], abs(amount))

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I like this much better (which, granted, is just a different way of writing the currently selected "best answer"):

```
money = float(1234.5)
print('$' + format(money, ',.2f'))
```

Or, if you REALLY don't like "adding" multiple strings to combine them, you could do this instead:

```
money = float(1234.5)
print('${0}'.format(format(money, ',.2f')))
```

I just think both of these styles are a bit easier to read.  :-)

(of course, you can still incorporate an If-Else to handle negative values as Eric suggests too)

Answer (score -2):

you said that:

```
`mony = float(1234.5)
print(money)      #output is 1234.5
'${:,.2f}'.format(money)
print(money)
```

did not work....
Have you coded exactly that way?
This should work (see the little difference):

```
money = float(1234.5)      #next you used format without printing, nor affecting value of "money"
amountAsFormattedString = '${:,.2f}'.format(money)
print( amountAsFormattedString )
```

Answer (score -2):

```
df_buy['BUY'] = df_buy['BUY'].astype('float')
df_buy['BUY'] = ['€ {:,.2f}'.format(i) for i in list(df_buy['BUY'])]
```