# Web2py Number Formatting for Thousands

Tags: python-2.x, web2py

I'm sort of new to Web2py. I have a system that's working just fine, but I want to make an improvement regarding visualization. There's a couple of fields that use numbers (defined as `double` in their respective `define_table` methods) to represent currency, but I want them to also show with a separator for thousands, such as `183,403,293.34`. I checked some documentation, but I couldn't find a direct way to handle this form of customization, though I could be missing something.

Any suggestions regarding this? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if representing currency, you should use the `decimal` field type rather than `double` (some calculations using `double` values may yield incorrect results due to the use of floating point representations internally). However, if using SQLite, there is no distinction between `decimal` and `double`, so in that case, you might want to multiply all values by 100 and instead store integers.

In any case, to display a given numeric value with thousands separators in Python, you can do:

```
'{:,}'.format(myvalue)
```

For more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10742904/440323 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21208495/440323.

If you are using the values via web2py functionality that makes use of the field's `represent` function (e.g., the grid or the `.render()` method), you can define a custom `represent` function, such as:

```
Field('amount', 'decimal(12, 2)',
      represent=lambda v, r: '{:,}'.format(v) if v is not None else '')
```

Comment: I see! The system uses PostgreSQL. I'm left in charge of maintaining and improving this system, so I'm not sure if I should change `double` to `float` due to this. Regardless, I'll try this out!

Comment: Alright, it worked like a charm! I'll have to explore this for further customization in other fields. However, I'm left unsure on the data type issue you commented.

Comment: Note, you would change `double` to `decimal`, not `float` (there is no `float` field type -- rather, `double` is implemented as floating point internally).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Python function of the locale module:

```
{{= locale.format ('%. 2f', your_value, grouping = True)}}
```