# how to convert a randomly chosen number into a currency?

Tags: python, currency

for my lottery i have a jackpot prize randomly chosen from 100,000 after its randomly chosen it goes to numbers how would i put it to be a currency? here is my jackpot code.

```
prize=random.randrange(100000)

print "welcome to the lottery!!!!"
time.sleep(1)
name=raw_input("What is your name?")
print name
print "welcome to the game show where you can win thousands of pounds by just ghuesing a number!!"
number=random.randrange(100)
while True:
    ghuess=input("state a number between 1-100")
    if ghuess>number:
        print "too high try again!"
    elif ghuess<number:
        print "too low try again!"
    else:
        # Jackpot, exit the loop.
        break
print "well done! ghuess you have won.."
time.sleep(1)
print "3"
time.sleep(1)
print "2"
time.sleep(1)
print "1"
time.sleep(1)
print prize
```

Comment: By "put it to be currency" do you mean print it with two decimals, commas between the thousands, etc? If so, please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python?rq=1

Comment: You can see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/320951/1982962) or this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8851191/1982962) it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you do is print the prize:

```
In [77]: print "{:,.2f}£".format(random.randrange(100000))
26,467.00£
```

Or if you want the currency symbol in the front

```
In [78]: print "£{:,.2f}".format(random.randrange(100000))
£80,244.00
```

If you already have the `prize` variable:

```
In [80]: print "£{:,.2f}".format(prize)
£64,058.00
```

[Here's a good explanation of the format specification.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that with string formatting as follows:

```
>>> print "${:,.2f}".format(prize)
```

Example:

```
>>> prize = 12345678   #just an example
>>> print "${:,.2f}".format(prize)
$12,345,678.00
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiple the random value by `0.01`. Like below:

```
prize=random.randrange(100000) * 0.01
```

Comment: That still lacks the currency symbol (if that should be dynamic) as well as the comma separation every three digits.