# Best Method to Format Currency in Python

Tags: python, formatting, numbers, currency, type-conversion

I'm trying to figure out the best/easiest method to format number into currency in python.  If the number is negative I want the minus sign to be before the dollar sign (ex.  -$123,323). Otherwise the number should appear in this form  (ex $123,323,323). Is there a built in python method to do this?

Comment: Have a read through the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python)

Comment: The suggested duplicate doesn't address the aspect of replacing the parenthesis with minus sign