# Return a list of lines as list of tuple with formatting the value with $

Tags: list, python-3.x, tuples

```
def format_Dollar_sign(list):

    lines=['book, 400.2\n', 'pen, 5\n', 'food,  200.5\n', 'gas, 20\n', 'food, 100\n', 'pen, 10\n', 'insurance, 171.35\n', 'gas, 35\n', 'book, 100\n', 'pen, 12\n', 'food, 320\n', 'gas,23.55\n', 'insurance, 110.25']

    #t=[]
    l1 = []
    l2 = []
    for line in lines:
        #l=[]
        parline =line[:-1]
        l1.append(parline)
        t = tuple(l1)
        l2.append(t)

        l1=[]
    L='[' + ', '.join('({})'.format(t[0]) for t in sorted(l2)) + ']'
    return L

print(format_Dollar_sign(list))
```

This code give me output as:
[(book,100),(book,400.2),(food, 200.5)...]

But I am looking output as:
[('book','$500.20'),('food', '$200.50')...]

The values are strings which start with a $  and they have two digits of accuracy after the decimal point. Moreover item names are sorted.

Could somebody suggest ways to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem as follows:

```
def format_Dollar_sign(list):

    lines=['book, 400.2\n', 'pen, 5\n', 'food,  200.5\n', 'gas, 20\n', 
            'food, 100\n', 'pen, 10\n', 'insurance, 171.35\n', 'gas, 35\n', 
            'book, 100\n', 'pen, 12\n', 'food, 320\n', 
            'gas,23.55\n', 'insurance, 110.25']

    my_dictionary = {}
    for line in lines:
        item, price= line.strip().split(',')

        my_dictionary[item.strip()] = my_dictionary.get(item.strip(),0) + float(price)

    dic={}
    for k,v in my_dictionary.items():
        dic[k]='${0:.2f}'.format(round(v,2))

    L=([(k,v) for k, v in dic.iteritems()])
    L.sort()

    return L
print(format_Dollar_sign(list))
```

Comment: I have to wait 18 hours because it is my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [locale](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/locale.html) module from the standard library takes care of this well. Here is one way to do it which gives your desired output:

```
import locale


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
lines=['book, 400.2\n', 'pen, 5\n', 'food,  200.5\n', 'gas, 20\n',
       'food, 100\n', 'pen, 10\n', 'insurance, 171.35\n', 'gas, 35\n',
       'book, 100\n', 'pen, 12\n', 'food, 320\n', 'gas,23.55\n',
       'insurance, 110.25']
itemTupleList = []

for i in lines:
    item = i.split(',')[0]

    # Here I am selecting price, ignoring new line characters, 
    # stripping leading/trailing spaces, converting string to float
    # and finally formatting.
    price = locale.currency(float(i.split(',')[1][:-1].strip()))

    itemTupleList.append((item, price))

print(sorted(itemTupleList))
```

This and other currency formatting solutions are discussed in this question: [Currency formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for your code. You use locale but could it be solved by formatting with "${:.2f}" to properly create and format strings for the total expenses. Moreover, your code return same item more than once. Here it needs to be added all the values to the same item, e.g. ('book':'$500.20') instead of ('book':'$400.20'), ('book':'$100'). Therefore this should return each tuple consists of the name of the item and total expense of that item. Hope this will clarify.

Comment: The desired output in your question shows book twice as a tuple.  You need to update it. It sounds like you already have a solution. In the future make sure to keep your question and desired output accurate.