# How to set locale / localize currency symbols in django template

Tags: python, django, locale

I'm trying to localize where I put my currency symbols in my django template (before vs after the number and spacing are both important). Example:

```
<span>{{ price }} {{ some_model.currency }}</span>
```

Where:

- `some_model` is an object, with property `currency` which is a symbol eg "€" or "$" or "RMB".
- In addition to the currency, I also know the locale `some_model.locale`.

In consulting the [localization docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/formatting/) it seems that django can format times and numbers, but not currencies? I could write a custom filter `{{ price | currency_filter }}`, but how do I set (and subsequently get) the session locale in the filter code? Ideally, I'd like to be able to set session's locale upon login, much like you can set the language:

```
from django.utils.translation import LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY
def login_view (request):
    ...
    request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = some_model.locale
```

and then write some sort of template filter:

```
def currency_filter (number):
   #hopefully some inbuilt session method to get the locale, then:
   if locale == 'en-US':
       return '$' + number
   #etc
```

Is this possible?

Comment: related?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python

Comment: I read that, but I want the locale to be set for the session, not for the entire python environment. There will be many concurrent sessions; I can't keep changing the global python locale.

Comment: What about apply change rate and taxes? I mean, is not enough just to change currency simbol.

Comment: In my particular circumstance, it is sufficient to change just the symbol. Taxes and exchange rates would form part of separate calculations.