# Python string with currency formatted

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to retrieve a dollar amount from my database, concatenate it with other information and have it print with 2 decimal points. I have tried so many different configurations I have lost tract but continue to get only one decimal point (or an error). Can someone please show me where I am losing it.

```
 #get payments on the permits
 for i in range(len(IDS)):  
     paydate = date.today() - timedelta(30)
     query = '''select `AmountPaid_credit`, `PayComment`, `DateReceived`, `WPTSinvoiceNo`
                 from Payments 
                 where `NPDES_ID` = ? and `DateReceived` >= ?'''
     PayStrings.append("\tNo Payment Recieved")
     for row in cur.execute(query, (IDS[i],paydate)):
         WPTSInv.append(row[3])
         d= row[2].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
         #create a payment string 
         PayStrings[i]="\t$"+str(row[0])+" - "+d+" - "+row[1]
```

returns this

```
$2000.0 - 02/09/2017 - 2017 APPLICATION FEE
```

but I need this

```
$2000.00 - 02/09/2017 - 2017 APPLICATION FEE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Currency formatting in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to Haifeng's answer, you could do the following

```
from decimal import Decimal

str(round(Decimal(row[0]), 2))
```

Edit: I would also like to add that there is a `locale` module and that it is probably a better solution, even if it is a little bit more work. You can see how to use it at this question here: [Currency formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you just converting decimal places:

```
   >>> value = "2000.0"
   >>> "{:.2f}".format(float(value))
   '2000.00'
```