# How to put a $ sign in a fixed width field in string.format()

Tags: python

I have the following line of code

```
print("Income $ {:>8,d} pays Flat tax ${:>9.2f} and Current tax ${:>9.2f}".format(income,tax,curr_tax))
```

It gives me the output

```
Income $   10,000 pays Flat tax $     0.00 and Current tax $     0.00
```

But I am trying to join the $ sign with the numbers without any spaces in between. How do we do this with `string.format()`

Edit:

This is the output I am trying to achieve

```
Income    $50,000 pays Flat tax    $780.00 and Current tax      $0.00
Income     $10,00 pays Flat tax      $0.00 and Current tax      $0.00
```

Comment: How about changing `>` to `<`?

Comment: Maybe use the locale module, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `format` within your `format`

```
print("Income {:>8} pays Flat tax {:>9} and Current tax {:>9}".format('${:,d}'.format(income), '${:.2f}'.format(tax), '${:.2f}'.format(curr_tax)))
```

Which gives

```
Income  $10,000 pays Flat tax     $0.00 and Current tax     $0.00
Income  $50,000 pays Flat tax   $780.00 and Current tax     $0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

[@aydow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51737950/564514) has a solid answer.

Alternatively, use @student comment by changing `>` to `<`:

```
print("Income ${:<8,d} pays Flat tax ${:<9.2f} and Current tax ${:<9.2f}".format(10000,0.00,0.00))
```

Results in:

```
Income $10,000   pays Flat tax $0.00      and Current tax $0.00
```

Still leaves blanks after values but not sure if that bugs you.