# Format currency using python template strings

Tags: python, template-strings

How can I format currency using python template strings? My goal is to generate the following string:

```
'Hello Johnny. It is $10'
```

I've tried the following:

```
from string import Template
d = {'name': 'Johnny', 'cost': 10}

Template('Hello ${name}. It is ${cost}').substitute(d)
# 'Hello Johnny. It is 10'

Template('Hello ${name}. It is $${cost}').substitute(d)
# 'Hello Johnny. It is ${cost}'

Template('Hello ${name}. It is $$cost').substitute(d)
# 'Hello Johnny. It is $cost'
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear that `$$` gives you a dollar sign and `${cost}` inserts your variable. So did you try `$$${cost}` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Currency formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python)

Comment: @khelwood that did it thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$$` escapes the dollar sign so three dollar signs are required:

```
Template('Hello ${name}. It is $$$cost').substitute(d)
# 'Hello Johnny. It is $10'
```