# How to add a comma in between thousands, and how do add a $ sign when making a table in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

We are creating a spreadsheet type table that holds values from user inputs. I need to have it so commas are added automatically. EX: 120220 needs to be 120,220 and I need a $ infront, so the final product would be $120,200

I have tried adding the money sign just infront naturally but it didn't work

```
print("1st Quarter Sales")

print("{:<20s}{:<20s}{:<20s}" .format("ITEM" , "QUANTITY" , "TOTAL SALES COST"))

print("{:<20s}{:<20d}{:<20d}" .format(desktop , desktop_1q , q1_desktop))

print("{:<20s}{:<20d}{:<20d}" .format(laptop, laptop_1q, q1_laptop))

print("{:<20s}{:<20d}{:<20d}" .format(printer, printer_1q, q1_printer))

print("Total Sales: $" , q1_total , sep="")
```

---

This is just the printed version, above are the inputs and then taking those inputs and multiplying them to get subtotals and stuff. "desktop" is just a string that says DESKTOP same with laptop and printer. desktop_1q printer_1q and laptop_1q is the quantity sold and for the q1_'S are the total sales so just cost of that product * quantity.

Final result with added commas and $ should look like $1,320,500

Comment: and what result do you actually get? `1320500` ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python), the [locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) module can do this for you.

Example:

```
import locale
...
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, '' )
q1_desktopCurr = locale.currency(q1_desktop, grouping=True)
...
print("{:<20s}{:<20d}{:<20}" .format(desktop , desktop_1q , q1_desktopCurr))
```