# How to make a number with decimals like currency in Python

Tags: python, rounding

How do I change a number like 3.3 to 3.30 to represent currency in python? does this include using **round()**?
[The code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPWBx.jpg)
   [The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EFIS.jpg)

I want the 5.3 to be 5.30 and if it is 2 I want it to be 2.00.

Comment: You should consider using integers for currency to avoid floating point rounding issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Currency formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python)

Comment: Hi.

In order to solve this question,could you tell us what exactly that you have tried.

The Solution mentioned by @JohnnyMopp will work but it's best for you to tell the code that you have written in order to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at float string formatting documentaiton.

In your case this will work.

```
'{:.2f}'.format(3)
```

Comment: Thanks, should I put this in before the round()

Comment: it's just a string operation, so you should use in only while printing your values.