# How can I override **kwargs value?

Tags: python, django, loops, dictionary

I have a dynamically generated dictionary. Example:

```
kwargs = { 'name':'Rafi', 'amount': 530}
```

This dictionary will be used as function parameter. But in case I need to change the value of `kwargs['amount']` often (not always).

```
def printer(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

for taka in range(100,kwargs['amount'],100):
    printer(**kwargs) #Each time (5 time) Output should be: { 'name':'Rafi', 'amount': 100}
    kwargs['amount']-=100

printer(**kwargs) #Output should be: { 'name':'Rafi', 'amount': 30}
```

It is not possible to change the `printer(**kwargs)` function. I have to do it through `for` loop.

I need to make some data entry, where until the balance is more than 100 ( `kwargs['amount'] > 100` ), every times $100 will be recorded.

Kindly, help me to figure it out.
(Working with django.)

Comment: `kwargs['amount'] if kwargs['amount'] <= 100 else 100`

Comment: Can you clarify what you have tried to or why you expect to already have ``kwargs['amount']`` clamped to 100? It would also help to know in far you feel clamping an integer is related to kwargs – the two are orthogonal. Do you need some logic (that makes both clamping and kwargs relevant) not shown in the question?

Comment: @wwii Sorry, But I'm unable to apply, what you said. Can you give me the code in more detail please(in my program's way)? Just for clarifying, kwargs['amount']=100 just for entry, as entry is $100.

Comment: Are you asking how to print an integer (`100`) as a string with a dollar sign in front of it? - [Currency formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python)

Comment: @wwii No! I used $ to indicate money. It's nothing

Answer (score 1):

A bit of naive approach but try this :

```
kwargs = { 'name':'Rafi', 'amount': 530}
  
def printer(**kwargs):
    if kwargs['amount'] <= 100:
        print(kwargs)
    else:
        kwargs_dummy = kwargs
        kwargs_dummy['amount'] = 100
        print(kwargs_dummy)

for taka in range(100,kwargs['amount'],100):
    printer(**kwargs) 
    kwargs['amount']-=100

printer(**kwargs)
```

Comment: I can't edit the `printer(**kwargs)` .The Code is far more complex. Actually, it is related to django model.