# Display "$" sign together with a float number

Tags: python

Hi I want to have my display to be for example, Single room    4    $720.00
But I do not know how to have the dollar sign there without having the error that it doesn't go with a float value.

```
single_room = int(input("Number of Single room: "))
total_single = 90 * single_room
print(f'{"Single room":<12}{single_room:^3}{"$" + total_single:>9.2f}')
```

This is an error because string doesn't go along with the float value. Please assist

Comment: You need the dollar sign to be as part of the string itself, not as part of a variable... `f'{"Single room":<12}{single_room:^3}${total_single:>9.2f}'`

Comment: Umm, sorry if this is a dumb question, but - I don't understand your print. Can you add an explanation of what the print line is supposed to do ?

Comment: @Programmer It says in the question, it's supposed to print `Single room 4 $720.00`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Hi, I tried to add the dollar sign there but it doesn't align to the right hand side

Comment: Check out [Currency formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/320929/10077).

Comment: @Tomerikoo I know this, but I wanted to understand his code (`f'{"Single room":<12}{single_room:^3}{"$" + total_single:>9.2f}'`) ...

Answer (score 1):

so you're f-string interpolating:

```
print(f"${total_single}")
```

should work, try and adapt it to your problem. The `$` is not part of the variable

Comment: But it's just a individual statement without the other details that I've included

Comment: so... add the other details? I don't understand what the difficulty is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the price to be aligned to the right together with the `$` sign, you can format in two steps:

```py
single_room = int(input("Number of Single room: "))
total_single = f"${90 * single_room:.2f}"
print(f'Single room {single_room:^3}{total_single:>9}')
```

Example run:

```
Number of Single room: 4
Single room  4   $360.00
```

First, format the `$` together with the price ***as a string*** into `total_single`. Then, align it as you want in the final string.